# Is there a way to get the git root directory in one command?

Tags: git, version-control

Mercurial has a way of printing the root directory (that contains .hg) via

```
hg root
```

Is there something equivalent in git to get the directory that contains the .git directory?

Comment: Good script Emil.
I make the script available online, and allowed the possibility to add a file/directory as argument.
http://github.com/Dieterbe/git-scripts/commit/3b7be5e25052e99d9be8ca7d9e6d5c91f8c2a14a

Comment: Also for anyone curious or searching `bzr root` was used a lot in Bazaar

Comment: Please take note of *'gcd' : Git-Aware 'cd' Relative to Repository Root with Auto-Completion* at http://jeetworks.org/node/52.

Comment: Consider [my answer below `git rev-parse --git-dir`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/958125/6309), as explained [in this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/957928/is-there-a-way-to-get-the-git-root-directory-in-one-command/958125?noredirect=1#comment28043274_958125)

Comment: @MichaWiedenmann: the link is dead.

Comment: @d33tah archive link https://web.archive.org/web/20130526035714/http://jeetworks.org/node/52

Answer (score 1649, accepted):

Yes:

```
git rev-parse --show-toplevel
```

If you want to replicate the Mercurial command more directly, you can create an [alias](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Git-Aliases):

```bash
git config --global alias.root 'rev-parse --show-toplevel'
```

and now `git root` will function just as `hg root`.

---

**Note**: In a submodule this will display the root directory of the *submodule* and **not** the parent repository. If you are using Git >=2.13 or above, there is a way that [submodules can show the superproject's root directory.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/958125/884640) If your git is older than that, [see this other answer.](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-parse#Documentation/git-rev-parse.txt---show-superproject-working-tree)

Comment: This is all I was able to find too; may want to alias it to git-top or something similar.

Comment: This gives me the path to the root of the top-level/root directory, which is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: I always define `git config --global alias.exec '!exec '` so I can do things like `git exec make`. This works because shell aliases are always executed in the top-level directory.

Comment: This is what `hg root` does. It prints out the top-level directory of your checked out repository. It doesn't switch you to it (and it couldn't, in fact, do so because of how the whole concept of current directory and your shell interact).

Comment: Smal caveat with this solution - it'll follow up any symbolic links. So, if you are in `~/my.proj/foo/bar`, and `~/my.proj` is symlinked to `~/src/my.proj`, the above command will move you to `~/src/my.proj`. Could be a problem, if whatever you want to do after that is not tree agnostic.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out; without your help, it'd be hard for me to guess to look into `git-rev-parse` -- because of its name suggesting it's about processing revision specifications. BTW, I'd be glad to see `git --work-tree` work similar to `git --exec-path[=<path>]`: "If no path is given, git will print the current setting"; at least, IMO, it'd be a logical place to look for such a feature.

Comment: How can I use this from within a git hook? Specifically, I'm doing a post-merge hook and I need to get the actual root directory of the local git repo.

Comment: The `git exec` alias can be combined with `pwd` to print the root directory: `git exec pwd`.Or sometimes, it's useful to have a subshell at the root temporarily, and then just exit to get back to the original task.

Comment: @jondavidjohn see https://gist.github.com/hilbix/7724772 `git config --global alias.top '!f() { GIT_TOP="${GIT_DIR%%/.git/modules/*}"; [ ".$GIT_TOP" != ".$GIT_DIR" ] && cd "$GIT_TOP"; exec "$@"; }; f'` and then `git top pwd`

Comment: This solution (and many others on this page that I've tried) do not work inside a git hook. To be more precise, it doesn't work when you're inside the project's `.git` directory.

Comment: this `git rev-parse && cd "$(git rev-parse --show-cdup)` doesn't work in the general case since `git rev-parse --show-cdup` returns the empty string in case you are allready in the git root dir. Concequence is you go to your home.

Comment: In Windows you'd get reversed slashes - use something like this to reverse them: `git rev-parse --show-toplevel > %TEMP%\GITROOT.TXT & SET /p BranchRoot=<%TEMP%\GITROOT.TXT & SET BranchRoot=%BranchRoot:/=\%`

Comment: As @Dennis notes, this doesn't work if inside the `.git` directory (or an external `$GIT_DIR` of a repository. See my answer for one that works anywhere in a repository, and fails gracefully in an external `$GIT_DIR`

Comment: what a travesty that the command is named that, wtf is "rev-parse"...reverse parse? "hg root" makes so much sense

Comment: @AlexanderMills it probably is "revision parse", but still strange to have this options there.

Comment: @AlexanderMills It appears "rev-parse" gets its name from originally being a helper for "rev-list" (revision list).  From the man page for `git-rev-parse`: "Many Git porcelainish commands take mixture of flags and parameters meant for the underlying git `rev-list` command they use internally and flags and parameters for the other commands they use downstream of `git rev-list`. This command is used to distinguish between them."

Comment: @jondavidjohn wish I saw that comment earlier. Thought I was losing my mind.

Comment: I don't think it's correct to say it "doesn't work" in a submodule, as getting the root directory of the submodule is exactly what I'd hope for. (my justification: wouldn't a shell script using this command always want the root directory of its own repository, and not a parent repository?) I submitted an edit which I feel adds a more helpful explanation.

Comment: To get it to work from the .git/hooks folder just `cd ../../;git rev-parse --show-top
level`

Comment: this solution doesn't work it some subdirectories of the root. for example in the root it works in the root/src it works, in root/src/tests it suddenly starts appending "/src/tests" to the end

Comment: @E. Sundin Hooks are executed from the repo root by default, no need to care about that if you meant that.

Comment: This does not work in a worktree (depending on what you want). It reports the root of the worktree rather than the original worktree. So you can't use it to find the main `.git` directory.

Comment: Useful note: you can set it to a bash variable with something like `ROOT=${ROOT:-$(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)}`

Comment: I often use `gcd` to go to project home as analogous to `cd` which takes to user home dir.
in my `.bashrc` `alias gcd='cd $(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)'`

Answer (score 117):

Has `--show-toplevel` only recently been added to `git rev-parse` or why is nobody mentioning it?

From the `git rev-parse` man page:

```
   --show-toplevel
       Show the absolute path of the top-level directory.
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out; without your help, it'd be hard for me to guess to look into `git-rev-parse` -- because of its name suggesting it's about processing revision specifications. BTW, I'd be glad to see `git --work-tree` work similar to `git --exec-path[=<path>]`: "If no path is given, git will print the current setting"; at least, IMO, it'd be a logical place to look for such a feature.

Comment: In particular, you can alias `root = rev-parse --show-toplevel` in your gitconfig.

Comment: in other words, you can do `git config --global alias.root "rev-parse --show-toplevel"` and then `git root` will be able to do the job

Comment: @RyanTheLeach `git rev-parse --show-toplevel` works when I tried it in a submodule. It prints the root dir of the git submodule. What does it print for you?

Comment: I was confused why this answer duplicated the top answer. Turns out that the top answer was edited from `--show-cdup` to `--show-top-level` in Feb 2011 (after this answer was submitted).

Comment: @wisbucky I was expecting the root directory of the container, aka the TOP LEVEL not just the nearest kinda top level.

Comment: Yes, it has only recently been added. I have access to a system with an older git that lacks it. It’s kinda annoying that the other answer was edited destructively.

Answer (score 109):

The `man` page for `git-config` (under *Alias*) says:

> If the alias expansion is prefixed with an exclamation point, it will be treated as a shell
> command. [...] Note that shell
> commands will be executed from the top-level directory of a repository, which may not
> necessarily be the current directory.

So, on UNIX you can do:

```bash
git config --global --add alias.root '!pwd'
```

Comment: it's the same as --rev-parse show-toplevel, but more elegant!

Comment: So, if you have a "git root" command, how can you put that in an alias? If I put it in my `.zshrc`, and I define `alias cg="cd $(git root)", the $() part gets evaluated at source-time, and always points to ~/dotfiles, as that is where my zshrc is.

Comment: @cormacrelf You don't put it in a shell alias. You can put it in a shell function or script.

Comment: this doesn't work when you are anywhere in the `.git/` directory. Then it returns your root directory as well as wherever you are in `.git/`

Comment: @cormacrelf Put it in single quotes instead of double quotes, then it will not be expanded at definition time, but at runtime.

Comment: It also fails if you're not in a Git repo.

Comment: @Mechanicalsnail Really? So what would you expect it to do outside repo?

Comment: @AloisMahdal actually for me it does not fail outside a repo, it simply reports the cwd.

Comment: @Omnifarious I personally don't know anyone who uses `command.com` (`cmd`) to make commits, but on Windows I guess you'd want `git config --add alias.root '!cd'` or alternatively `'!echo %CD%'`. Accepted answer, however, is best if you need cross-platform compatibility.

Comment: clever. also works with symlinks better than accepted answer

Comment: @zelk use single quotes, not double quotes. Double-quoted strings are evaluated at alias definition time.

Comment: A variation on this, if you don't want to modify a global alias: `git -c alias.root=!pwd root`

Answer (score 98):

How about "**`git rev-parse --git-dir`**" ?

```
F:\prog\git\test\copyMerge\dirWithConflicts>git rev-parse --git-dir
F:/prog/git/test/copyMerge/.git
```

The `--git-dir` option seems to work.

It does work even in a [bare repository](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37992400/6309), while `git rev-parse --show-toplevel` would trigger (in said bare repository) a "`fatal: this operation must be run in a work tree`".

From [git rev-parse manual page](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rev-parse.html):

```
--git-dir

    Show $GIT_DIR if defined else show the path to the .git directory.
```

You can see it in action in this [`git setup-sh` script](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-parse#Documentation/git-rev-parse.txt---show-superproject-working-tree).

If you are in a submodule folder, [**with Git >=2.13**, use](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52913255/6309):

```
git rev-parse --show-superproject-working-tree
```

If you are using `git rev-parse --show-toplevel`, [make sure it is with Git 2.25+ (Q1 2020)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59339751/6309).

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, since it gives the absolute path. I tried to make an alias that will also cd into this directory, but that doesn't work with "cdroot = !cd $(git rev-parse --git-dir)" sadly.

Comment: Oh wait, this was close but it gets the actual .git dir, not the base of the git repo.

Also, the .git directory could be elsewhere, so this isn't what I was looking for exactly.

Comment: Right, I see now what you were actually looking for. --show-cdup is more appropriate then. I leave my answer for illustrating the difference between the two options.

Comment: It also appears that this command gives a relative path for `.git` if you're already in the root directory. (At least, it does on msysgit.)

Comment: +1, this is the only answer that answers the original question "get the directory that contains the .git directory?", amusing to see that the OP itself mention "the .git directory might be elsewhere".

Comment: This is the only solution that works on windows AND gives a parsable result when using git submodules (e.g. c:\repositories\myrepo\.git\modules\mysubmodule). That makes it the most robust solution especially in a reusable script.

Comment: The full solution along those lines is:

`(root=$(git rev-parse --git-dir)/ && cd ${root%%/.git/*} && git rev-parse && pwd)` but this doesn't cover external `$GIT_DIR`s which are named other than `.git`

For a full solution, see my answer below.

Comment: Thanks. I actually wanted the git dir and this works on submodules too, which don't necessarily have a `.git/` folder below their toplevel folder.

Comment: @joeytwiddle Nice! 7 years later, and this answer is still relevant!

Comment: @BlairHolloway There does exist `--path-format=(absolute|relative)` to override the relative behavior. I was not able to answer the question of whether or not this was an option in 2010.

Answer (score 52):

To write a simple answer here, so that we can use

```
git root
```

to do the job, simply configure your git by using

```bash
git config --global alias.root "rev-parse --show-toplevel"
```

and then you might want to add the following to your `~/.bashrc`:

```bash
alias cdroot='cd $(git root)'
```

so that you can just use `cdroot` to go to the top of your repo.

Comment: Very nice! Ultimately convenient!

Answer (score 28):

If you're already in the top-level or not in a git repository `cd $(git rev-parse --show-cdup)` will take you home (just cd).  `cd ./$(git rev-parse --show-cdup)` is one way of fixing that.

Comment: Another option is to quote it: `cd "$(git rev-parse --show-cdup)"`. This works because `cd ""` takes you nowhere, rather than back `$HOME`. And it's best practice to quote $() invocations anyway, in case they output something with spaces (not that this command will in this case, though).

Comment: This answer works well even if you changed directory to your git repo [via a symlink](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/180620/understanding-directory-symlinks-traversals-and-the-parent-directory). Some of the other examples don't work as expected when your git repo is under a symlink as they do not resolve the git's root directory relative to bash's `$PWD`. This example will resolve git's root relative to `$PWD` instead of `realpath $PWD`.

Answer (score 21):

**Short solutions that work with submodules, in hooks, and inside the `.git` directory**

Here's the short answer that most will want:

```bash
r=$(git rev-parse --git-dir) && r=$(cd "$r" && pwd)/ && echo "${r%%/.git/*}"
```

This will work anywhere in a git working tree (including inside the `.git` directory), but assumes that repository directory(s) are called `.git` (which is the default). With submodules, this will go to the root of the outermost containing repository.

If you want to get to the root of the current submodule use:

```bash
echo $(r=$(git rev-parse --show-toplevel) && ([[ -n $r ]] && echo "$r" || (cd $(git rev-parse --git-dir)/.. && pwd) ))
```

To easily execute a command in your submodule root, under `[alias]` in your `.gitconfig`, add:

```bash
sh = "!f() { root=$(pwd)/ && cd ${root%%/.git/*} && git rev-parse && exec \"$@\"; }; f"
```

This allows you to easily do things like `git sh ag <string>`

**Robust solution that supports differently named or external `.git` or `$GIT_DIR` directories.**

Note that `$GIT_DIR` may point somewhere external (and not be called `.git`), hence the need for further checking.

Put this in your `.bashrc`:

```bash
# Print the name of the git working tree's root directory
function git_root() {
  local root first_commit
  # git displays its own error if not in a repository
  root=$(git rev-parse --show-toplevel) || return
  if [[ -n $root ]]; then
    echo $root
    return
  elif [[ $(git rev-parse --is-inside-git-dir) = true ]]; then
    # We're inside the .git directory
    # Store the commit id of the first commit to compare later
    # It's possible that $GIT_DIR points somewhere not inside the repo
    first_commit=$(git rev-list --parents HEAD | tail -1) ||
      echo "$0: Can't get initial commit" 2>&1 && false && return
    root=$(git rev-parse --git-dir)/.. &&
      # subshell so we don't change the user's working directory
    ( cd "$root" &&
      if [[ $(git rev-list --parents HEAD | tail -1) = $first_commit ]]; then
        pwd
      else
        echo "$FUNCNAME: git directory is not inside its repository" 2>&1
        false
      fi
    )
  else
    echo "$FUNCNAME: Can't determine repository root" 2>&1
    false
  fi
}

# Change working directory to git repository root
function cd_git_root() {
  local root
  root=$(git_root) || return 1  # git_root will print any errors
  cd "$root"
}
```

Execute it by typing `git_root` (after restarting your shell: `exec bash`)

Comment: This code is being code-reviewed at [Robust bash function to find the root of a git repository](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/138255/robust-bash-function-to-find-the-root-of-a-git-repository). Look there for updates.

Comment: Nice. More complex that what I proposed 7 years ago (http://stackoverflow.com/a/958125/6309), but still +1

Comment: The shorter solution along those lines is:

`(root=$(git rev-parse --git-dir)/ && cd ${root%%/.git/*} && git rev-parse && pwd)` but this doesn't cover external `$GIT_DIR`s which are named other than `.git`

Comment: I wonder if this take into account the multiple worktrees that are now possible in git 2.5+ (http://stackoverflow.com/a/30185564/6309)

Comment: Your comment link to "Robust bash function to find the root ..." now gives a 404.

Comment: @ErikE it says `deleted by Community♦ Mar 2 at 0:00 (RemoveDeadQuestions)`

Comment: Do you have any updates that came out of that code review?

Comment: @ErikE sadly not, it was deleted because of no response to the question. Anyways, I feel it's pretty robust, and `shellcheck` clean.

Comment: Hooks are executed from the repo root by default, no need to care about that within hooks themselves.

Answer (score 18):

As others have noted, the core of the solution is to use `git rev-parse --show-cdup`. However, there are a few of edge cases to address:

1. When the cwd already is the root of the working tree, the command yields an empty string.
   <sub>Actually it produces an empty line, but command substitution strip off the trailing line break. The final result is an empty string.</sub>

```
Most answers suggest prepending the output with `./` so that an empty output becomes `"./"` before it is fed to `cd`.
```

1. When GIT_WORK_TREE is set to a location that is not the parent of the cwd, the output may be an absolute pathname.

```
Prepending `./` is wrong in this situation. If a `./` is prepended to an absolute path, it becomes a relative path (and they only refer to the same location if the cwd is the root directory of the system).
```

1. The output may contain whitespace.

```
This really only applies in the second case, but it has an easy fix: use double quotes around the command substitution (and any subsequent uses of the value).
```

As other answers have noted, we can do `cd "./$(git rev-parse --show-cdup)"`, but this breaks in the second edge case (and the third edge case if we leave off the double quotes).

Many shells treat `cd ""` as a no-op, so for those shells we could do `cd "$(git rev-parse --show-cdup)"` (the double quotes protect the empty string as an argument in the first edge case, and preserve whitespace in the third edge case). POSIX says the result of `cd ""` is unspecified, so it may be best to avoid making this assumption.

A solution that works in all of the above cases requires a test of some sort. Done explicitly, it might look like this:

```bash
cdup="$(git rev-parse --show-cdup)" && test -n "$cdup" && cd "$cdup"
```

No `cd` is done for the first edge case.

If it is acceptable to run `cd .` for the first edge case, then the conditional can be done in the expansion of the parameter:

```bash
cdup="$(git rev-parse --show-cdup)" && cd "${cdup:-.}"
```

Comment: Why don't you just use "git config --global --add alias.root '!pwd'" and a shell alias gitroot='cd `git root`' that the answer above you uses?

Comment: Using an alias might not be possible, e.g. if you want to script it and cannot rely on a custom alias.

Comment: Sub Modules are another corner case.

Answer (score 17):

To calculate the absolute path of the current git root directory, say for use in a shell script, use this combination of readlink and git rev-parse:

```bash
gitroot=$(readlink -f ./$(git rev-parse --show-cdup))
```

`git-rev-parse --show-cdup` gives you the right number of ".."s to get
to the root from your cwd, or the empty string if you are at the root.
Then prepend "./" to deal with the empty string case and use
`readlink -f` to translate to a full path.

You could also create a `git-root` command in your PATH as a shell script to apply this technique:

```bash
cat > ~/bin/git-root << EOF
#!/bin/sh -e
cdup=$(git rev-parse --show-cdup)
exec readlink -f ./$cdup
EOF
chmod 755 ~/bin/git-root
```

(The above can be pasted into a terminal to create git-root and set execute bits; the actual script is in lines 2, 3 and 4.)

And then you'd be able to run `git root` to get the root of your current tree.
Note that in the shell script, use "-e" to cause the shell to exit if the rev-parse fails so that you can properly get the exit status and error message if you are not in a git directory.

Comment: Your examples will break if the git "root" directory path contains spaces. Always use `"$(git rev-parse ...)"` instead of hacks like `./$(git rev-parse ...)`.

Comment: `readlink -f` doesn't work the same on BSD. See [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1055671/62269) for workarounds. The Python answer will probably work without installing anything: `python -c 'import os, sys; print(os.path.realpath(sys.argv[1]))' "$(git rev-parse --show-cdup)"`.

Answer (score 16):

Just in case if you're feeding this path to the Git itself, use `:/`

```bash
# this adds the whole working tree from any directory in the repo
git add :/

# and is equal to
git add $(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)
```

Answer (score 10):

To amend the "git config" answer just a bit:

```bash
git config --global --add alias.root '!pwd -P'
```

and get the path cleaned up.  Very nice.

Answer (score 10):

Since [Git 2.13.0](https://lwn.net/Articles/722364/), it supports a new option to show the path of the root project, which works even when being used from inside a submodule:

```
git rev-parse --show-superproject-working-tree
```

Unfortunately for us, it prints nothing if we're not in a submodule. In that case, `--show-toplevel` still works. This Bash code will do the job regardless of whether we're in a submodule:

```bash
super=$(git rev-parse --show-superproject-working-tree)
case "$super" in
"")
  git rev-parse --show-toplevel
  ;;
*)
  echo "$super"
esac
```

Comment: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-parse#git-rev-parse---show-superproject-working-tree. Interesting. I must have missed that one. +1

Comment: Warning though: " Outputs nothing if the current repository is not used as a submodule by any project."

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I hadn't noticed that.

Comment: Also pay attention to nested submodules.

Comment: @VonC, you can add `--show-toplevel` to fall back to git root behaviour. By piping to `tail -n1` or `head -n1` you can grab one or the other depending on what is available.

Comment: @swalog Yes, indeed. I believe I mention `--show-toplevel` in [my own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/958125/6309).

Comment: I submitted an edit with a solution that falls back to `--show-toplevel` when necessary.

Answer (score 9):

If you're looking for a good alias to do this plus not blow up `cd` if you aren't in a git dir:

```bash
alias ..g='git rev-parse && cd "$(git rev-parse --show-cdup)"'
```

Answer (score 8):

### **`git-extras`**

adds `$ git root`
see https://github.com/tj/git-extras/blob/master/Commands.md#git-root

```
$ pwd
.../very-deep-from-root-directory
$ cd `git root`
$ git add . && git commit
```

#### Availability of git-extras

- homebrew(osx)/linuxbrew(linux) `$ brew install git-extras`
- debian/ubuntu repos (https://packages.debian.org/sid/git-extras) `$ apt-get install git-extras`

Answer (score 6):

This shell alias works whether you are in a git subdir, or at the top level:

```bash
alias gr='[ ! -z `git rev-parse --show-toplevel` ] && cd `git rev-parse --show-toplevel || pwd`'
```

updated to use modern syntax instead of backticks:

```bash
alias gr='[ ! -z $(git rev-parse --show-toplevel) ] && cd $(git rev-parse --show-toplevel || pwd)'
```

Answer (score 5):

```bash
alias git-root='cd \`git rev-parse --git-dir\`; cd ..'
```

Everything else fails at some point either going to the home directory or just miserably failing. This is the quickest and shortest way to get back to the GIT_DIR.

Comment: It does seem like 'git rev-parse --git-dir' is the cleanest solution.

Comment: This fails, when `$GIT_DIR` is detached from the workingtree using `.git`-Files and `gitdir: SOMEPATH`.  Consequently this fails for submodules, too, where `$GIT_DIR` contains `.git/modules/SUBMODULEPATH`.

Answer (score 5):

```bash
$ git config alias.root '!pwd'
# then you have:
$ git root
```

Comment: This alias will fail as a global. Use this instead (in ~/.gitconfig):
`[alias]
 findroot = "!f () { [[ -d ".git" ]] && echo "Found git in [`pwd`]" && exit 0; cd .. && echo "IN `pwd`" && f;}; f"`

Comment: why downvote? Please highlight any error or suggest improvement instead.

Comment: For me `git config --global alias.root '!pwd'` works.  I was unable to spot any case where it acts differently to the non-global variant.  (Unix, git 1.7.10.4)  BTW: Your `findroot` requires a `/.git` to avoid an endless recursion.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a script that I've written that handles both cases: 1) repository with a workspace, 2) bare repository.

https://gist.github.com/jdsumsion/6282953

`git-root` (executable file in your path):

```bash
#!/bin/bash
GIT_DIR=`git rev-parse --git-dir` &&
(
  if [ `basename $GIT_DIR` = ".git" ]; then
    # handle normal git repos (with a .git dir)
    cd $GIT_DIR/..
  else
    # handle bare git repos (the repo IS a xxx.git dir)
    cd $GIT_DIR
  fi
  pwd
)
```

Hopefully this is helpful.

Comment: Keith, thank you for the suggestion, I've included the script.

Comment: I actually upvoted the top answer because I realized the `git exec` idea is more helpful in non-bare repositories.  However, this script in my answer handles the bare vs. non-bare case correctly, which could be of use to someone, so I'm leaving this answer here.

Comment: However this fails within `git submodule`s where `$GIT_DIR` contains something like `/.git/modules/SUBMODULE`.  Also you assume, that the `.git` directory is part of the worktree in the non-bare case.

Answer (score 4):

### Pre-Configured Shell Aliases in Shell Frameworks

If you use a shell framework, there might already be a shell alias available:

- `$ grt` in [oh-my-zsh (68k)](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/wiki/Plugin:git) (`cd $(git rev-parse --show-toplevel || echo ".")`)
- `$ git-root` in [prezto (8.8k)](https://github.com/sorin-ionescu/prezto/tree/master/modules/git#functions) (displays the path to the working tree root)
- `$ g..` [zimfw (1k)](https://github.com/zimfw/zimfw/tree/master/modules/git#misc) (changes the current directory to the top level of the working tree.)

Answer (score 3):

I wanted to expand upon Daniel Brockman's excellent comment.

Defining `git config --global alias.exec '!exec '` allows you to do things like `git exec make` because, as `man git-config` states:

> If the alias expansion is prefixed with an exclamation point, it will be treated as a shell command. [...] Note that shell commands will be executed from the top-level directory of a repository, which may not necessarily be the current directory.

It's also handy to know that `$GIT_PREFIX` will be the path to the current directory relative to the top-level directory of a repository. But, knowing it is only half the battle™. Shell variable expansion makes it rather hard to use. So I suggest using `bash -c` like so:

```
git exec bash -c 'ls -l $GIT_PREFIX'
```

other commands include:

```
git exec pwd
git exec make
```

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone needs a POSIX compliant way of doing this, without needing `git` executable:

[`git-root`](https://gist.github.com/swarminglogic/b84dd42441e5a95c6cb9cf1402b49847):

```bash
#$1: Path to child directory
git_root_recurse_parent() {
    # Check if cwd is a git root directory
    if [ -d .git/objects -a -d .git/refs -a -f .git/HEAD ] ; then
        pwd
        return 0
    fi

    # Check if recursion should end (typically if cwd is /)
    if [ "${1}" = "$(pwd)" ] ; then
        return 1
    fi

    # Check parent directory in the same way
    local cwd=$(pwd)
    cd ..
    git_root_recurse_parent "${cwd}"
}

git_root_recurse_parent
```

---

If you just want the functionality as part of a script, remove the shebang, and replace the last `git_root_recurse_parent` line with:

```bash
git_root() {
    (git_root_recurse_parent)
}
```

Comment: Caveat: If this is NOT called in a git repo then the recursion does not end at all.

Comment: @A.H. Second `if` statement was supposed to check whether you've changed directory in the recursion. If it remains in the same directory, it assumes you're stuck somewhere (e.g. `/`), and brakes recursion. The bug is fixed, and should now work as expected. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1):

When in a Git worktree, `--git-dir` gets the path of the worktree metadata inside the `.git` folder. To get the path of the actual `.git` folder where hooks can be installed, use `--git-common-dir` instead:

```
/Projects/mywork$ git rev-parse --git-dir
/Projects/app/.git/worktrees/mywork
/Projects/mywork$ git rev-parse --git-common-dir
/Projects/app/.git
```

EDIT: For hooks, there is a better solution:

```
/Projects/mywork$ git rev-parse --git-path hooks
/Projects/app/.git/hooks
```

Answer (score 0):

`git rev-parse --show-prefix` will return path from current folder to root folder of git repo.

Answer (score -2):

Had to solve this myself today. Solved it in C# as I needed it for a program, but I guess it can be esily rewritten. Consider this Public Domain.

```cs
public static string GetGitRoot (string file_path) {

    file_path = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName (file_path);
    
    while (file_path != null) {
    
        if (Directory.Exists (System.IO.Path.Combine (file_path, ".git")))
            return file_path;
    
        file_path = Directory.GetParent (file_path).FullName;
    
    }

    return null;
    
}
```

Comment: This fails when the working directory and the `.git` directory are in separate paths (see the other answers/comments regarding GIT_WORK_TREE and GIT_DIR).

Comment: not one command