# git: a quick command to go to root of the working tree

Tags: git, bash, scripting

I wanted a simple git command to go up to the "root" of the repository.

I started with a script, but figured that I cannot change active directory of the shell, I had to do a function. Unfortunately, I cannot call it directly with the non-dash form "git root", for instance.

```
function git-root() {
 if [ -d .git ]; then
  return 0
 fi

 A=..
 while ! [ -d $A/.git ]; do 
  A="$A/.."
 done
 cd $A
}
```

Do you have a better solution? (the function has been written quickly, suggestions are welcome)

Comment: what about when you have nested git repos? eg, my whole home directory is a git repo for the purposes of configuration files.

Comment: Do you mean the root of the working tree, rather than of the repository?

Comment: better solution for config files is to create separate directory with symlinks from home folder like ~/.profile => ~/dot-files/profile

Comment: exact dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/957928/is-there-a-way-to-get-to-the-git-root-directory-in-one-command

Comment: Thanks for the question, it helped me with a similar task except not for git :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to get the git root directory in one command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/957928/is-there-a-way-to-get-the-git-root-directory-in-one-command)

Answer (score 63, accepted):

This has been asked before, [Is there a way to get the git root directory in one command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/957928/is-there-a-way-to-get-to-the-git-root-directory-in-one-command) Copying @docgnome's answer, he writes

```
cd $(git rev-parse --show-cdup)
```

Make an alias if you like:

```
alias git-root='cd $(git rev-parse --show-cdup)'
```

Comment: why not using git's alias mechanism?

Comment: I guess that would be fine too :)

Comment: I would use  cd $(git rev-parse --show-toplevel). Takes care of the edge case when you are in the root dir. I imagine this wasn't available before.

Comment: downvoted because while close, it doesn’t handle being in the root directory already.  See http://stackoverflow.com/a/14127035/125349

Comment: I agree with @DaveAbrahams

Comment: Asa - beautiful and elegant!

Comment: as a tweak, I vote function - 

function gitroot () { cd ./$(git rev-parse --show-cdup) ; }

Comment: **Note** this doesn't work if inside the `.git` directory (or an external `$GIT_DIR` of a repository). See my answer for one that works anywhere in a repository, and fails gracefully in an external `$GIT_DIR`

Comment: u0b34a0f6ae: because `cd` is a builtin of your shell, and if you execute it in a subprocess it won't change your shell's current directory

Answer (score 64):

Simpler still, steal from [Is there a way to get the git root directory in one command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/957928/is-there-a-way-to-get-the-git-root-directory-in-one-command) , and make an alias (as suggested by Peter) from

```
cd "$(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)"
```

This works whether you're in the root directory or not.

Comment: Works perfectly and elegant, too.  What more could I ask?

Comment: Note this also supports spaces in directory names too!

Comment: for windows: if ur git repo is referenced via a junctionpoint and ur $PWD is within such a junction then this will CD u to the original/physical location. This doesnt happen for Peter's answer.

Comment: I aliased this - note the escaped double quotes: `alias gitroot="cd \"$(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)\""`.

Answer (score 15):

Peter's answer above works great if you're in a subdirectory of the git root.  If you're already in the git root, it'll throw you back to $HOME.  To prevent this, we can use some bash conditionals.

```
if [ "`git rev-parse --show-cdup`" != "" ]; then cd `git rev-parse --show-cdup`; fi
```

so the alias becomes:

```
alias git-root='if [ "`git rev-parse --show-cdup`" != "" ]; then cd `git rev-parse --show-cdup`; fi'
```

Comment: Makes a nice function too 
function cgr() {
if [ "`git rev-parse --show-cdup`" != "" ]; then cd `git rev-parse --show-cdup`; fi
}

Comment: @Christian The backticks in what you wrote got interpreted as slackoverflow formatting. This should look right, substituting $() for backticks:
`function cgr() { if [ "$(git rev-parse --show-cdup)" != "" ]; then cd $(git rev-parse --show-cdup); fi }`

Comment: `--show-toplevel` will handle when you are in git root. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/14127035

Answer (score 6):

```
$ git config alias.root '!pwd'
$ git root
```

Comment: Interesting... It appears `git` sets the working directory of shells to the root of the repository. It's probably best not to rely on this behaviour, however.

Answer (score 3):

**Short solutions that work with submodules, in hooks, and inside the `.git` directory**

Here's the short answer that most will want:

```
r=$(git rev-parse --git-dir) && r=$(cd "$r" && pwd)/ && cd "${r%%/.git/*}"
```

This will work anywhere in a git working tree (including inside the `.git` directory), but assumes that repository directory(s) are called `.git` (which is the default). With submodules, this will go to the root of the outermost containing repository.

If you want to get to the root of the current submodule use:

```
cd ''$(r=$(git rev-parse --show-toplevel) && [[ -n $r ]] && echo "$r" || (cd $(git rev-parse --git-dir)/.. && pwd) )
```

To easily execute a command in your submodule root, under `[alias]` in your `.gitconfig`, add:

```
sh = "!f() { root=$(pwd)/ && cd ${root%%/.git/*} && git rev-parse && exec \"$@\"; }; f"
```

This allows you to easily do things like `git sh ag <string>`

**Robust solution that supports differently named or external `.git` or `$GIT_DIR` directories.**

Note that `$GIT_DIR` may point somewhere external (and not be called `.git`), hence the need for further checking.

Put this in your `.bashrc`:

```
# Print the name of the git working tree's root directory
function git_root() {
  local root first_commit
  # git displays its own error if not in a repository
  root=$(git rev-parse --show-toplevel) || return
  if [[ -n $root ]]; then
    echo $root
    return
  elif [[ $(git rev-parse --is-inside-git-dir) = true ]]; then
    # We're inside the .git directory
    # Store the commit id of the first commit to compare later
    # It's possible that $GIT_DIR points somewhere not inside the repo
    first_commit=$(git rev-list --parents HEAD | tail -1) ||
      echo "$0: Can't get initial commit" 2>&1 && false && return
    root=$(git rev-parse --git-dir)/.. &&
      # subshell so we don't change the user's working directory
    ( cd "$root" &&
      if [[ $(git rev-list --parents HEAD | tail -1) = $first_commit ]]; then
        pwd
      else
        echo "$FUNCNAME: git directory is not inside its repository" 2>&1
        false
      fi
    )
  else
    echo "$FUNCNAME: Can't determine repository root" 2>&1
    false
  fi
}

# Change working directory to git repository root
function cd_git_root() {
  local root
  root=$(git_root) || return 1  # git_root will print any errors
  cd "$root"
}
```

Execute it by typing `cd_git_root` (after restarting your shell: `exec bash`)

Comment: This code is being code-reviewed at [Robust bash function to find the root of a git repository](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/138255/robust-bash-function-to-find-the-root-of-a-git-repository). Look there for updates.

Comment: "This question was removed from Code Review Stack Exchange for reasons of moderation."

Comment: @kelvin It got no replies (other than a suggestion to use `shellcheck`) and was `deleted by Community♦ Mar 2 at 0:00 (RemoveDeadQuestions)`

Comment: This also works with worktrees.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, changing your current directory can only be done by the shell, not by any subprocess. By the time git gets around to parsing your command, it's already too late -- git has already been spawned in a separate process.

Here's a really gross, untested shell function that just might do what you want:

```
function git() {
    if [ "$1" == "root" ]; then
        git-root
    else
        git "$@"
    fi
}
```

Comment: This function would just replace git, rather being able to run alongside git

Answer (score 1):

A better alias working in bash and zsh is:

```sh
alias git-root='cd "$(git rev-parse --show-cdup)"'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [oh-my-zsh](https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh) and you added the `git` plugin in your

```
plugins+=(git)
```

`.zshrc` configuration file, the follwing command (alias) works:

```
grt
```

This alias is defined the following way:

```
grt='cd "$(git rev-parse --show-toplevel \|\| echo .)"'
```

Answer (score -1):

Peter's answer is the master reply. Many others observed that it doesn't work if you're already in the git root directory, unfortunately their solutions are overwhelming complex.

Here my one-liner:

```
alias cd-gitroot='cd $(git rev-parse --show-cdup)/.'
```