# How can I configure git difftool/mergetool to pass full path of files?

Tags: windows, git

I've configured git difftool/mergetool in a .gitconfig file using $LOCAL, $REMOTE, and $MERGED. These are replaced with relative paths to the files I'm working with. The problem is, when my tool is launched it needs the full path to these files and returns errors.

Is it possible to pass the full path of files in a diff/merge *without* using an external shell script?

Thank you.

Comment: Doesn't `GIT_WORK_TREE` give you the base to the worktree?

Comment: This variable doesn't seem to be recognized when I add it to my .gitcongig (empty). Does it need to be set somewhere?

Comment: Are you using Cygwin git or msysgit? Which merge/diff tools are you trying to use?

Answer (score 0):

Could your tool make use of a git command like:

```
 git rev-parse --show-cdup
```

That would give you the "[root of the working tree](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1571525/6309)" you are in.