# Git pull is not returning absolute path in verbose

Tags: git, git-svn

I am trying to pull from GIT using verbose, it shows all the updated files but it is not showing the absolute path for those files.Is there a way to get full path for the updated files.

i tried command:git pull --verbose

output:
Updating b88b206..4a5f5dd
Fast-forward
 .../main/com/manh/cbo/syscode/finitevalue/TESBSysCodeType.java         | 3 ---
 1 file changed, 3 deletions(-)

i want something like:

Updating b88b206..4a5f5dd
Fast-forward
 C:/GIT/WM2013/te/manifest/JavaSource/main/com/manh/cbo/syscode/finitevalue/TESBSysCodeType.java

Answer (score 2):

git shortens the paths to fit in 80 chars.

`git pull` implies `git merge` which has `--stat` by default. Unfortunately, this `--stat` has no `width` option unlike `diff`, `log` or `show`.

So, to see the changed files, save the current SHA1 into a shell variable:

```
oldsha=`git rev-parse HEAD`
```

, do `git pull` and then:

```
git diff --stat=1000,1000 $oldsha
```

or

```
git diff --name-only $oldsha
```

Answer (score 0):

No: it could be related to the pager configuration: see "[git diff - handling long lines?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/136178/6309)".

Check if the output is more complete with a:

```
 GIT_PAGER='' git pull --verbose
```

---

One workaround could be to pipe the output of that command in order to:

- find the path of what has been produced by the `git pull`,
- replace `.../main` by `<root of your folder>/main`.

See for instance "[git: a quick command to go to root of the working tree](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1571525/6309)".
(or:

- "[How to find the path of the local git repository when I am possibly in a subdirectory](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12293994/6309)"
- "[Is there a way to get the git root directory in one command?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/958125/6309)"

  ```
   git rev-parse --git-dir
  ```

)

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply. i am pulling the code from root directory only.in my project i have multiple modules, i need to know the module names which are having changes for every pull.But pull is not returning the relative path from root.in the previous example:C:/GIT/WM2013/te is the root, when i pull atleast i want output from manifest/JavaSource/main/com/manh/cbo/syscode/finitevalue/TESBSysCodeType.java  (manifest is the module).