# How can I find the root git directory reliably from a git hook?

Tags: bash, git, githooks

Given 2 git repositories (Product A and Product B), with submodules (CommonSubmodule, SomeOtherSubmodule)

```
D:\Repositories\ProductA\
D:\Repositories\ProductA\CommonSubmodule
D:\Repositories\ProductA\SomeOtherSubmodule
D:\Repositories\ProductA\SomeOtherSubmodule\
D:\Repositories\ProductB\SomeOtherSubmodule\
D:\Repositories\ProductB\CommonSubmodule\
```

I've found a script online that allows for branches to be logged via a post_checkout hook

```
#!/bin/sh

previous_head_ref=$1
new_head_ref=$2
is_branch_checkout=$3

if [[ "$previous_head_ref" != "$new_head_ref" ]] && [[ "$is_branch_checkout" == 1 ]]; then
    branch=$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)
    #if [[ "develop" != "$branch" ]]; then
        path="$(dirname "$0")/.."
        logfile="$path/x_branch_log"
        ts=$(date +%s)
        echo "$branch|1|$ts" >> $logfile
        echo "Logging $branch|1|$ts to $logfile"
        echo PWD is $PWD
    #fi
fi
```

In a post_checkout context, how can I get the root directory (D:\Repositories) no matter how deep in the submodule the hook is installed, without encoding absolute paths?

```
D:\Repositories\
```

Additionally, how can I get the root product directory, e.g.

```
D:\Repositories\ProductA\
D:\Repositories\ProductB\
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments I got on my answer on [Git repo root folder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/958125/6309), check the return value of a

```
git rev-parse --git-dir
```

You might have to iterate (if you are in a submodule of a submodule of a parent repo), but it should return the root folder of the parent repo.

Comment: Doing this on my command line, in the working directory of CommonSubmodule results in D:/Repositories/ProductA/.git/modules/CommonSubmodule

Comment: Yes, treeline the module part, and you get your root folder

Comment: @RyanTheLeach Don't mind the downvote, I still consider this a valid answer to your problem.

Comment: @RyanTheLeach I know, I meant, "please, (you) do not mind the downvote" ;) Or "don't attach the downvote too much importance"

Comment: I'm tempted to trust you based on other answers I've seen across SO relating to git hooks, But I'm an utter bash noob, and I've been trying to find out how to reliably manipulate file paths, but as far as I can tell, people just tend to hack it together using string manipulation?  What is 'treeline' that you mentioned?

Comment: @RyanTheLeach DO I understand correctly that you want the root folder of the top parent repo? That is: if a repo A has a submodule B which has a submodule C, you would want the root folder of A when queried from within C?

Comment: I'm actually after 1 level higher then that again, but that should be trivial once I have the root folder of A. Just append a ../ my biggest problem by far is getting it to be reliable, and get a sane error when it's not easily possible, as I'm trying to convince others to also use my git hook eventually.

Comment: @RyanTheLeach The parent folder of A?

Comment: @RyanTheLeach I'll have a script for you before that. I wanted to be sure of what you are after.

Comment: My end goal is the parent folder of A. However the question is asking about the root folder of A if available. I was just going to append a \..\ afterwards to go up a directory.

Comment: @RyanTheLeach Try https://stackoverflow.com/a/38843585/6309 as an example of script.