# How do I find out what Git thinks the top-level working directory is?

Tags: find, directory, git-config, git

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to get to the git root directory in one command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/957928/is-there-a-way-to-get-to-the-git-root-directory-in-one-command)

Sometimes, I'm confused with git thinking that I'm inside a Git working dir, but it's not obvious to me what the top-level working directory (containing `.git/`) is. (Probably, that repo was created by a mistake.)

So, how do I find out the top-level Git repo directory if I'm somewhere inside the subdirectories? How do I ask `git` to print what it thinks the current top-level working directory is?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Try this:

```
git rev-parse --show-toplevel
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out; without your help, it'd be hard for me to guess to look into `git-rev-parse` -- because of its name suggesting it's about processing revision specifications. BTW, I'd be glad to see `git --work-tree` work similar to `git --exec-path[=<path>]`: "If no path is given, git will print the current setting"; at least, IMO, it'd be a logical place to look for such a feature.

Comment: **Note** that this fails if inside the `.git` directory. See the marked duplicate for a solution.

Comment: This command also does not work from a submodule

Comment: the name that is returned from the --show-toplevel flag; can this be changed?? I have a mapped network drive I did the git init on and now when I am actually on the server (not on the mapped side of it) the drive names are different. Meaning what gets returned on the --show-toplevel is not correct when I am on the server. It needs to return D:/ rather than Y:/  this is what I can't find how to do

Comment: @CotyEmbry Perhaps [`git rev-parse --show-cdup`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-parse#git-rev-parse---show-cdup) will better suit you. Anyway, that's strange that the absolute path reported on your server is not correct...

Answer (score 2):

I've written a simple script ([git-find-git-dirs](https://gitorious.org/git-shortcuts/mainline/blobs/master/git-find-git-dirs) in my "[git-shortcuts](https://gitorious.org/git-shortcuts#more)" collection) to make such queries to Git handy:

```
#!/bin/bash

# find-git-dirs -- A simple script to "find" (i.e., "print") the GIT_DIR, as assumed by Git. (Useful if you are in a subdir, and you are not sure about the top-level repo dir.)

SUBDIRECTORY_OK=yes
. "$(git --exec-path)/git-sh-setup"

echo "GIT_DIR=$GIT_DIR"
```

and put it to `~/bin/`; now I can do my simple query like this:

```
$ git find-git-dirs
GIT_DIR=/home/imz/.git
GIT_WORK_TREE=
$
```

The only thing I lack from the initial question is the printing of the top-level *working* dir, now it just prints the path to the internal git repo dir...