# the command what git repository am I using in

Tags: git, github

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to get to the git root directory in one command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/957928/is-there-a-way-to-get-to-the-git-root-directory-in-one-command)

how can i check what git repository am I using ?

I can see the result with '`git init`'.

git init returns '`Reinitialized existing Git repository in c:/Users/k-9/.git/`'

but I think git init is not a proper command.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`git rev-parse --show-toplevel` will show the top-level directory of the repository if your working directory is a git repository.

```
$ git rev-parse --show-toplevel
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
$ cd gitrepo
$ git rev-parse --show-toplevel
/home/jamessan/gitrepo
```