# How to git grep in the whole tree when I'm in a subdirectory?

Tags: git, grep

Normally when I issue `git grep`, it will only search the current directory and below, for instance

```
$ cat A
1
$ cd d
$ cat B
1
$ git grep 1
B:1
$ cd ..;git grep 1
A:1
B:1
```

How can I tell `git grep` "search the entire tree, no matter the current working directory I'm in"?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Git aliases that run shell commands are always executed in the top level directory (see the [`git config` man page](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-alias)), so you can add this to your `.gitconfig` file:

```
[alias]
    rgrep = !git grep
```

Alternatively, you could use `git rev-parse --show-toplevel` to get the root directory, which you could then pass to `git grep` as the basis of a script or alias:

```
git grep $pattern -- `git rev-parse --show-toplevel`
```

Comment: still not ideal, since paths won't run from top level, but nice.

Comment: @Chi-Lan: Looking at this again, I don't see any problem with paths and a `!git grep` alias. The whole command (including the arguments you pass to it) is executed in the repository's root directly, so the paths should be relative to the repository root too. My final update was no different to this solution (so I've removed it).

Comment: The git config man page link is broken. Can you please update it?

Comment: It works but it does not show the find files full path from the root directory, would it be possible also show the find file's full path from  git root path?

Answer (score 20):

**`:/` magic path**

```
git grep pattern -- :/
```

works on Git 1.9.1 for this and other commands, as mentioned at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31696782/895245

TODO I can't find a clear documentation reference after grepping the docs, but it is mentioned some times in the release notes at:

Documentation/RelNotes/1.7.6.txt:39:   be a no-op, but "git add -u :/" would add the updated contents of

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your Git config file to make a `grepall` alias that will do what you want:

```
[alias]
    grepall = !git grep
```

(Non-native aliases, e.g. those that begin with a `!`, are always run from the top level of the repository.)

Comment: still not ideal, since paths won't show from current directory, but thanks