# batch script get path of parent directory that contains the .git folder

Tags: windows, git, batch-file

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to get the git root directory in one command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/957928/is-there-a-way-to-get-the-git-root-directory-in-one-command)

Let's say the repository starts at

```
C:\myrepo\
and the prompt is at 
C:\myrepo\folderone\folderoneb\folderonec
```

I need a batch script that can go up until it finds

```
C:\myrepo.git and return C:\myrepo
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Is there a way to get the git root directory in one command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/957928/is-there-a-way-to-get-the-git-root-directory-in-one-command)

Just use the command `git rev-parse --show-toplevel` and use its output in the way you need

And yes, this works on Windows, too ;)