# Script getting git working directory root?

Tags: linux, git, bash

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to get the git root directory in one command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/957928/is-there-a-way-to-get-the-git-root-directory-in-one-command)

I am writing a bash script (actually a Makefile) that needs to use an argument that is a directory relative to the root of the git working directory that contains the current directory.

That is:

```
 /home/me$ git clone /abc/foo.git

 directory foo created

 /home/me$ cd foo/bar

 /home/me/foo/bar$ execute_script.sh

 hello /home/me/foo/baz
```

execute_script.sh is as follows:

```
 echo hello `git something`/baz
```

What is git something ?  It should return the absolute path of the current git working root.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you are looking for

[Is there a way to get the git root directory in one command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/957928/is-there-a-way-to-get-the-git-root-directory-in-one-command)

root="'git rev-parse --git-dir`/.."

echo hello $root/baz

Comment: This answer actually doesn't work if you're in a git worktree. Using `git rev-parse --show-toplevel` seems to work in all cases that I tried.

Answer (score 12):

Well, if you know you're going to be in the bar folder, you can try:

```
echo hello `pwd`/../baz
```

Edit: As @Andrew Tomazos pointed out earlier to a different thread, you can do

```
echo hello `git rev-parse --show-toplevel`/baz
```