# How do I delete the newline from a process output?

Tags: elisp

I call git get the toplevel dir (according to
[Is there a way to get the git root directory in one command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/957928/is-there-a-way-to-get-the-git-root-directory-in-one-command)
).

```
(let ((tmpbuffer (get-buffer-create (make-temp-name "git"))))
  (call-process "git" nil tmpbuffer nil "rev-parse" "--show-toplevel")
  (with-current-buffer tmpbuffer
    (with-output-to-string
      (princ (buffer-string))
      (kill-buffer))))
```

But there's a trailing newline in the string returned. I'm not sure how to get rid of it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think you can do

```lisp
(replace-regexp-in-string "\n$" "" 
              (shell-command-to-string "git rev-parse --show-toplevel"))
```

Comment: This doesn't just remove newlines at the end of the output. I've added an alternative answer.

Comment: Can you explain why not?

Answer (score 11):

If you only want to remove a newline at the very end of the output, use

```
(replace-regexp-in-string "\n\\'" "" 
  (shell-command-to-string "git rev-parse --show-toplevel"))
```

The accepted answer also replaces pairs of newlines (`"\n\n"`) in the output by single newlines (`"\n"`), because `$` matches at the end of the string or after a newline, while `\\'` only matches at the end of the string.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming it is stored in a variable `output-string`, the final newline at the end can be removed this way:

```
(substring output-string 0 -1)
```

With the `shell-command` way, it would look like this:

```
(substring
  (shell-command-to-string "git rev-parse --show-toplevel")
  0 -1)
```

Answer (score 2):

If You are OK with *awesome* external package.

use [s-trim](https://github.com/magnars/s.el#s-trim-s)

```lisp
ELISP> (shell-command-to-string "light -G")
"60.00\n"

ELISP> (s-trim (shell-command-to-string "light -G"))
"60.00"
```