# String interpolation inside lisp statement

Tags: functional-programming, elisp, elfeed

```
(insert "[" (shell-command-to-string "~/lombardi/http_fetch.sh") "]")
```

How can I pass an argument to the http_fetch.sh function. This argument is arrived at by evaluating `(elfeed-entry-link entry)`

I tried using a ' in front but ended up with a bash error.

Answer (score 2):

Use `concat` to append the string resulting from calling `elfeed-entry-link` to the end of the shell command:

```
(insert "["
        (shell-command-to-string
         (concat "~/lombardi/http_fetch.sh " (shell-quote-argument (elfeed-entry-link entry))))
        "]")
```

The `shell-quote-argument` protects the command in case the result of `elfeed-entry-link` contains shell metacharacters or whitespace. (EDIT: removed manual quoting originally suggested here and used `shell-quote-argument` instead, thanks to the comment from @phils.)

Note also that the result of `shell-command-to-string` will most likely include a final newline, so be sure to [strip it out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29777273) if you don't want it.

Comment: Don't try to quote the arguments manually. Call `shell-quote-argument` on each argument to a generated shell command. (It is generally good practice to do this whether you think you need to or not.)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `format` to interpolate strings.

```
(insert "["
        (shell-command-to-string
         (format "~/lombardi/http_fetch.sh %s" (elfeed-entry-link entry)))
        "]")
```

As Steve mentions, you should really use `shell-quote-argument` to ensure you handle spaces and quotes correctly when you pass the argument.