# What is the syntax of git's repository root path?

Tags: git

When using `git add -u` I can provide a path as the last argument, e.g. `git add -u .`. How does one give the repositories root path?

I would like to use this to quickly add all changes to tracked files to the index, including changes to files further up the directory tree.

**Example**

```
$ git status
# On branch mul
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add ..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- ..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#       modified:   ../../../foo.mwb
#
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

Comment: @larsmans: Not a duplicate.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The colon `:` helps here, you can refer to the root of the repository by `:/`:

```
git init test
cd test
mkdir a
touch a/a
git add a
git commit -m a
# Here comes the interesting part:
cd a
touch ../root
git add :/
git commit -m root
```

The script above initializes a toy repository that contains one single file `a` in a subdirectory `a`. In "the interesting part", it changes to the `a` directory, creates an empty file in the root of the repository and adds it using the `:/` reference. The `-u` switch works as usual (not shown in the script).

The [manual of `git-rev-parse`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rev-parse.html) reads:

> `<rev>:<path>`, e.g. `HEAD:README`, **`:README`**, `master:./README`
>
> A suffix `:` followed by a path names the blob or tree at the given path in the tree-ish object named by the part before the colon. **`:path` (with an empty part before the colon) is a special case of the syntax described next: content recorded in the index at the given path.** A path starting with `./` or `../` is relative to the current working directory. The given path will be converted to be relative to the working tree’s root directory. This is most useful to address a blob or tree from a commit or tree that has the same tree structure as the working tree.

Unfortunately, the `bash` autocompletion feature doesn't work for the `:/` construct.

This [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/957928/946850) asks about finding the absolute path of the repository; of course, you can also do `git add $(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)` as outlined in the [top-voted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/957978/946850).

Comment: I presume `ci` is an alias for `commit`?

Answer (score 1):

Related question: [What does "git add -A :/" do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22047909/what-does-git-add-a-do)

The recent wording of [the documentation of `git-add`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-add) says: `git add <options> <pathspec>...`. And `:/` in the context of `git-add` is a *pathspec*. *pathspec* is documented in [gitglossary(7)](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitglossary.html), where it is described that `:` has a special meaning as the first character of a *pathspec*. See [my answer for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22049939/1728537).