# What does "git add -A :/" do?

Tags: git

I have seen colleagues using `git add -A :/` for staging files in repositories, but I am unable to find what that does in the [documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-add.html). What am I missing?

**Note**: I understand what the flag `-A` does (this question has been answered in SO [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/572549/difference-between-git-add-a-and-git-add/572660#572660)). My question is specifically about `:/` and the role it plays in `git add`.

Comment: "git add -A" is equivalent to "git add .; git add -u" "git add -A" is just a short cut of doing both

Comment: I *think* `:` it refers to the root directory of the repository, but I haven't found that in the documentation.

Comment: I've never seen that syntax before, but it looks similar to that of [refspec](http://git-scm.com/book/ch9-5.html).

Comment: @KeithThompson Have a look at the definition of path spec in https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitglossary.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As you already know the `-A` option, let's talk about `git add :/` only. According to the [documentation of git-add](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-add), the last argument is a *pathspec*. The definition of it is in [the documentation of gitglossary](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitglossary.html). Let me quote the releant parts (I put the important sentences in bold):

> **A pathspec that begins with a colon : has special meaning.** In the short form, the leading colon : is followed by zero or more "magic signature" letters  (which optionally is terminated by another colon :), and the remainder is the pattern to match against the path. The optional colon that terminates the "magic signature" can be omitted if the pattern begins with a character that cannot be a "magic signature" and is not a colon.
>
> In the long form, the leading colon : is followed by a open parenthesis (, a comma-separated list of zero or more "magic words", and a close parentheses ), and the remainder is the pattern to match against the path.
>
> The "magic signature" consists of an ASCII symbol that is not alphanumeric.
>
> **top /**
>
> **The magic word top (mnemonic: /) makes the pattern match from the root of the working tree, even when you are running the command from inside a subdirectory.**
>
> Currently only the slash / is recognized as the "magic signature", but it is envisioned that we will support more types of magic in later versions of git.

You can see that if a *pathspec* begins by `:/` or `:(top)` then that part of the *pathspec* is by definition the root of the working tree.

`git add  :/` stages all files in the working tree.

Comment: The documentation of `git-add` (at least the one you linked to) does not seem to mention **pathspec** anywhere. I just fixed it for you.

Comment: @user815423426 I do not understand. The SYNOPSIS of [git-add(1)](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-add) and the first paragraph of OPTIONS both mention *pathspec*. But the definition of a *pathspec* is hard to find. It is described in [gitglossary(7)](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitglossary.html)

Comment: @user815423426 Sorry. I read you edit, and indeed the link to `git-add(1)` I gave was a different version. On my machine, I have Git-1.8.3 and its documentation pages, and it does talk about *pathspec*. Older versions talk about filepattern.

Answer (score 4):

(This answer originally talked about *refspecs*, which turned out to be irrelevant and incorrect.)

As [lrineau's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22049939/827263) correctly points out, the `:` character in this case is part of the syntax of a *pathspec*.

Documentation on pathspecs is annoyingly difficult to find, but there's a "gitglossary" man page, available either by typing `man gitglossary` or visiting [this web page](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitglossary.html).

The relevant part:

> A pathspec that begins with a colon `:` has special meaning. In the
>   short form, the leading colon `:` is followed by zero or more "magic
>   signature" letters (which optionally is terminated by another colon
>   :), and the remainder is the pattern to match against the path. The
>   optional colon that terminates the "magic signature" can be omitted if
>   the pattern begins with a character that cannot be a "magic signature"
>   and is not a colon.
>
> In the long form ... *[snip]*.
>
> The "magic signature" consists of an ASCII symbol that is not
>   alphanumeric.
>
> `top /`
>   The magic word `top` (mnemonic: `/`) makes the pattern match from
>   the root of the working tree, even when you are running the command
>   from inside a subdirectory.

The conclusion is the same as in my original answer: `:/` refers to the root directory of the current working tree.

Comment: But `git add` takes path specifiers, not refspecs.  The `:/` syntax smells of after-the-fact workaround for old `git add` behavior: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/21954767/1256452

Comment: That is a **pathspec** and not a **refspec**.

Comment: @lrineau: Please feel free to edit my answer or post your own. I use git, but I've managed to avoid learning about refspecs and pathspecs.

Comment: I have improved my answer by quoting gitglossary(7), as you did.