# What is the GIT equivalent of clearcase's "cleartool pwv"

Tags: git, clearcase, cleartool

When using clearcase

```
cleartool pwv
```

gives the working directory view. I would like to find something equivalent for that in GIT.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pwv` does give the current ClearCase (snapshot or dynamic) view, but `git` doesn't have the concept of a "view" registered in a server, since everything is local.

It is just a local folder including a `.git` and a working tree.

The closest of a ct pwv would be:

```
git rev-parse --show-toplevel
```

(or [you can use a bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18339166/6309))

That would give the top folder of the local repository (but no "name" for the workspace)

See other differences between ClearCase and Git in "[What are the basic clearcase concepts every developer should know?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/645771/6309)".