# Does the target directory for a git clone have to match the repo name?

Tags: git, github

In other words, I have a repo up on Github called st3_packages (https://github.com/pitosalas/st3_packages).

I want to do a git clone and have it create a directory on my local computer called "`Packages`".
Is that possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it is possible:

```
git clone https://github.com/pitosalas/st3_packages Packages
```

You can specify the local root directory when using [git clone](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone).

```
<directory>
```

> The name of a new directory to clone into.
>   The "humanish" part of the source repository is used if no directory is explicitly given (`repo` for `/path/to/repo.git` and `foo` for `host.xz:foo/.git`).
>   Cloning into an existing directory is only allowed if the directory is empty.

---

As [Chris](https://stackoverflow.com/users/354577/chris) [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20863994/does-the-target-directory-for-a-git-clone-have-to-match-the-repo-name/20864005?noredirect=1#comment31303430_20864005), you can then rename that top directory.
Git only cares about the `.git` within said top folder, which [you can get with various commands](https://stackoverflow.com/q/957928/6309):

```
git rev-parse --show-toplevel
git rev-parse --git-dir
```

Comment: Furthermore, the top-level directory may be freely renamed after it is created.