# How to show full paths in git diff?

Tags: git-diff

How do I show full paths in git diff?
One can use '--dst-prefix=$PWD' and '--src-prefix=$PWD' but this is fragile as it won't work in many cases, eg with --no-index, or when running the commond from a subdirectory without using --relative=realpath_to_cwd

Answer (score 1):

It should be possible to:

- get the the path of the root folder of the repo: see "[Is there a way to get the git root directory in one command?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/957978/6309)"
- use that path in the `--relative`, `--dst-prefix` and `--src-prefix` options.

That would be more robust than `$PWD`.

Comment: 4 years later ;) What command did you type? With which version of Git?

Comment: here's an example command (using git version 2.17.1 but irrelevant)
"git diff --no-index `get_file1` `get_file2`"

The cmd `get_file1` or ``get_file2` could return either absolute or relative path, so  '--dst-prefix=$PWD' won't work (eg when path is already  absolute)

`git rev-parse --show-toplevel` makes no sense in the case of `--no-index` in general, since the files i'm comparing may not even be in a git repo.

more info [here](https://public-inbox.org/git/CANri+ExMY9G9aSm2TumHd8a9p2ZVXqcBOV-H=7P-_Xh_ng=Cpg@mail.gmail.com/T/#rd4b7a754b4771346a4997b30f3e8c0b41964c0ac)