# Cannot create repository with ungit

Tags: node.js, git, repository, ungit

After installing ungit, I tried to test it with a mock folder (testungit).

I used ungit CLI, then I have got this page.

[image]

I would like to have this page to create a repository.

[image]

During this installation, I had those lines :

```
npm WARN engine forever-monitor@1.1.0: wanted: {"node":"0.8.x"} (current: {"node":"v0.10.29","npm":"1.4.14"})

> typechecker@2.0.8 preinstall /usr/local/lib/node_modules/ungit/node_modules/getmac/node_modules/extract-opts/node_modules/typechecker
> node ./cyclic.js

npm WARN engine hawk@0.10.2: wanted: {"node":"0.8.x"} (current: {"node":"v0.10.29","npm":"1.4.14"})
npm WARN engine boom@0.3.8: wanted: {"node":"0.8.x"} (current: {"node":"v0.10.29","npm":"1.4.14"})
npm WARN engine hoek@0.7.6: wanted: {"node":"0.8.x"} (current: {"node":"v0.10.29","npm":"1.4.14"})
npm WARN engine cryptiles@0.1.3: wanted: {"node":"0.8.x"} (current: {"node":"v0.10.29","npm":"1.4.14"})
npm WARN engine sntp@0.1.4: wanted: {"node":"0.8.x"} (current: {"node":"v0.10.29","npm":"1.4.14"})
npm WARN engine hawk@0.10.2: wanted: {"node":"0.8.x"} (current: {"node":"v0.10.29","npm":"1.4.14"})
npm WARN engine hoek@0.7.6: wanted: {"node":"0.8.x"} (current: {"node":"v0.10.29","npm":"1.4.14"})
npm WARN engine boom@0.3.8: wanted: {"node":"0.8.x"} (current: {"node":"v0.10.29","npm":"1.4.14"})
npm WARN engine sntp@0.1.4: wanted: {"node":"0.8.x"} (current: {"node":"v0.10.29","npm":"1.4.14"})
npm WARN engine cryptiles@0.1.3: wanted: {"node":"0.8.x"} (current: {"node":"v0.10.29","npm":"1.4.14"})
```

Is that a problem ?

I don't know if I have to change something in .ungitrc

Comment: It just looks like your `testungit` directory is already initialized as a Git repository. What's the output of running `git status` on the command line in that directory?

Comment: I cannot post it, it too long ...
But it seems that it is tracking all changes from my Documents folder :$
Do you think I should uninstall git and reinstall it ?

Comment: Reinstalling Git likely won't make a difference. Are you deliberately tracking changes in your Documents folder, or is that an accident?

Comment: That is an accident... any ideas to solve that ?

Comment: If the root is the Documents folder, you probably have a `.git` directory in that folder. That's your Git repository. Delete the `.git` directory and you should be good to go!

Comment: I do not have this file in my folder. Furthermore, I tested to create a folder in the Desktop folder. Then, I launched the ungit command when i was inside this folder(the new one). But that is the same result that in my Documents folder.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56437/discussion-between-chris-and-defoncesko).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `testungit` folder, you can type:

```
git rev-parse --git-dir
# or even
cd "$(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)"
```

If there is a git repo defined in one of the parent folders, that will give you the actual root folder of that repo (as in "[Is there a way to get the git root directory in one command?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/957928/6309)").