# Trying to commit a directory that has been git init. Receiving " fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories) "

Tags: git, github

I can commit individual files within the directory, but it will not allow me to commit the whole directory.

Comment: The problem would be easier to diagnose if you added some minimal code reproducing the error.

Answer (score 4):

You need to be *in* that folder for the `git commit` to work.
And you need to add it first

This wouldn't work:

```
git init test
git add test
git commit -m "add test"
```

This would work:

```
git init test
cd test
git add .
git commit -m "add test"
```

You can check if the folder is [part of a repo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/958125/6309):

```
cd test
git rev-parse --git-dir
```

Make sure no environment variable like `GIT_DIR` is defined (which would make the git command look for a git repo elsewhere)