# How does git know what repo it is in?

Tags: linux, git, githooks, git-post-receive

I'm writing a post-receive hook and looking to dynamically set the repo location to a variable.

The post-receive hook is located in: /git/hub/poc.git/hooks/
The repo location is: /git/prime/poc

Is there anyway I can determine the repo location in post-receive on the fly? (prefer not to chop up the post-receive pwd and "guess" at it)

Comment: That doesn't make sense to me. Isn't the git repo in `/git/hub/poc.git` ?

Comment: I can't really understand your question either, but maybe `git rev-parse --show-toplevel` will help.

Comment: I am looking for the location of the committed files... am I mis-speaking when I call that the repo? sorry just got started with git last week

Comment: @AndrewC That's exactly what i'm looking for! (git rev-parse --show-toplevel) THANKS!

Comment: In that case you are a dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/957928/is-there-a-way-to-get-the-git-root-directory-in-one-command so I won't bother making my comment an answer.

Comment: Thanks for that -- after some further tinkering this command only works to show the toplevel of the path I'm in. It doesn't provide the same information from within the hooks dir most likely because the hooks path is not a git repo.