# Git alias which uses aliases

Tags: git, git-config, git-alias

I would like to use the assume command in order to chain it 5 times.

```
[alias]
assume = update-index --assume-unchanged
unassume = update-index --no-assume-unchanged
assumeall = "!git ls-files ../.idea/misc.xml | xargs git assume"
unassumeall = "!git assumed | xargs git update-index --no-assume-unchanged"
```

but when running i get this error:

```
fatal: '../.idea/misc.xml' is outside repository
```

The assume, unassume, unassumeall work just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

`[alias]
  assumeall = "!git ls-files $(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)/.idea/misc.xml | xargs git assume"`

Comment: how do i do i supply a number of files.

Comment: You don't need to explicitly search for the toplevel. Git aliases with a leading `!` will be treated as shell commands and be executed in the toplevel folder of the repository. This means that you could simply do `!git ls-files .idea.misc.xml ...`. [Take a look at the config docu](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-config).

Comment: I obviously meant to write `!git ls-files .idea/misc.xml ...`

Answer (score 1):

Simply check if '`../.idea/misc.xml`' reference a file which is a git repo.

For instance, if you go to the `.idea/` folder, and [look for the root folder of the git repo](https://stackoverflow.com/q/957928/6309), does it return a folder?

```
git rev-parse --show-toplevel
```

If not, `.idea/` is outside a git repo, and [`git ls-files`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-files) cannot be applied.