# How Can You Push The Current Directly to GitHub?

Tags: git, github

In my current directory, I `git add` `origin` and `fetch`. However, when I push, `git push origin master` does more than just push the current directory and all the subfolders. Somehow the `origin` and `fetch` are set to my parent directory.

So, in context, I have `/goo/foo/bar/baz`. I am in `bar` and I want only `baz` to show up in my GitHub. Instead, I somehow push `/goo`.

(In real life, I just `devise practice` to be pushed [here](https://github.com/kchens/devise-users-rails-skeleton)).

Answer (score 1):

If you `git init` has been done in `/goo` (ie you have a `/goo/.git` folder), being in `bar/` and pushing doesn't mean: push only bar at the top of my remote GitHub repo.

It means: push whatever has changed in my `/goo/...` repo, respecting the structure within `/goo/`.

Check [what is the root folder of your repo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/957978/6309):

```
pwd
  /goo/foo/bar
cd "$(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)"
```

Comment: Yes, `goo` is the root folder. I remove the `remote` `origin and `fetch`. However, when I try to re-add `origin` and `fetch` into `baz`, `goo` becomes the root folder again.

Comment: @KevinC Adding/removing the remote has no effect on where the git repo is. I would rather git clone the remote repo elsewhere, and copy exactly what I need in that local repo.

Answer (score 0):

You have to `git remote remove fetch`. BUT, `git remote add origin <repo name>`. Then, when you `git push master`, you should only get the current directory in github.