# List files with git ls-files from root instead of current working directory

Tags: git

I'm looking for a command similar to the following, but that always lists from the repository root, rather than the current working directory:

```
git ls-files --cached --others --exclude-standard
```

If possible I'd rather not use bash/batch, since I'm looking for a cross-platform solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you can create an alias,

```
git config --global alias.ls-files-root "! git ls-files"
```

Then you should be able to do

```
git ls-files-root --cached --others --exclude-standard
```

Explanation: Aliases starting with '!' are executed as shell commands from the top-level directory.
Related: [Is there a way to get the git root directory in one command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/957928/).

Comment: On Windows it needs double quotes - do double quotes also work for Linux?

Comment: No (in some shells, e.g. `bash`, `!` performs history expansion inside double quotes but not single quotes). I'll have to think about it -- double quotes won't work on Linux, single quotes and backslashes won't work on Windows...

Comment: PowerShell on Windows should work with single quotes, if that's any help.

Comment: It's been a while, but I just realised you can use `"! git ls-files"` in bash (the space after the exclamation mark prevents history expansion). That should be portable.

Answer (score 13):

If [Git aliases](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30190360/62269) aren't an option, it can be done in 2 commands:

```
git ls-files $(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)
```

Comment: This is nice because it gives me the relative path to those files rather than the path from root - thanks!

Comment: this is helpful for scripts

Answer (score 1):

Commands that expect pathspecs as an arg generally allow for leading `:/` to mean the root of the working tree. So you can use:

```hs
git ls-files --full-name :/
```

This is better than combining with `git rev-parse --show-toplevel` output, because the latter won't allow you to find specific file in the repo. I.e. this: `git ls-files -- $(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)"*filename.c"` won't work, but this `git ls-files ":/*filename.c"` does. And it's shorter too.