# error: open("AppData/Local/Comms/UnistoreDB/USS.jtx"): Permission denied

Tags: git, github

I use `$ git add .`
but it is print:

```
error: open("AppData/Local/Comms/UnistoreDB/USS.jtx"): Permission
denied error: unable to index file
AppData/Local/Comms/UnistoreDB/USS.jtx fatal: adding files failed
```

If I use run to open it in Windows 10 pro 1703, it asks to open with another program (last time it says open by virtual machine 8210b_xxxx I forgot what's the numbers on x)
what's wrong ?

```
system ver.:windows pro 1703 
antivirus:windows defender 
git ver.:Git-2.15.1.2-64-bit
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you have a git repository defined in `C:\users\yourLogin`, which seems odd and not recommended.
Try and confirm that with [`git rev-parse --show-toplevel`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/957978/6309)

Anyway, one reason that file might not be added is because another process is keeping an handle on it. You can check that with [Process Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) (type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>, and look for `USS.jtx`)

But more importantly, check where you Git repo should be, because it should not be in `C:\users\yourLogin`.

Comment: but my repo is in the C:/Users/user /.git how should I do?

Comment: @黃天貓 If you did not intent to have a Git repo there (and don't care about your history), you should delete, or at least rename the .git/ folder, and `git init .` in the right folder (meaning creating the Git repo where you actually want it to be)

Comment: and I can't find witch ************* process open USS.jtx

Comment: @黃天貓 That is OK, because once your Git repo will be where you need it to be, it won't matter anymore.

Comment: can I delete .git?

Comment: @黃天貓 Again, if you do not care about any commit done in it, yes. Or, just to be safe, you can rename it for safekeeping.

Comment: fuuuuuuuu...... I switch it to the D:/ but git says:fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
what the

Comment: @黃天貓 You do a `git init .` only in the folder which contains your project. That is not `D:\` (you don't want *all* files in D:\ to be in a Git repo) but cd `D:\path\to\my\project`, then `git init .`