# Why are my files from a seperate folder being added to my new git repository?

Tags: git, bitbucket

So, I'm working on a project for school, and our professor wants us to send him our code with a bitbucket git repository.  I've been using bitbucket the whole semester, but now when I go to make a new repository in a new folder, it adds commits and files from a different repository from a different folder.

I navigate to my new folder Spring2018/iOS/Projects/Scoreboard, and do the git commands to add this folder to my new repo in bitbucket.  However, when ever I commit and then push, it also includes all the files and commits from a different project in a different path - Spring2018/GameDev/Projects/Shooter.  After the Spring2018 folder, these are two different paths.  Why are all my commits from the other folder being added to my new repository?

As a side note, it also always gives me the error:
fatal: remote origin already exists.
So I need to set the url:
git remote set-url origin https://.....

Any help would be extremely helpful.  Thank you!

Comment: Sounds like one of the parent folders is already a git repo. Try [`git rev-parse --show-toplevel`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/957978/6352706) to see the root of the git repo.

Answer (score 1):

You are, I think, creating a git repository inside another.

I would say you have an extra .git file in Spring2018 or somewhere preceding this folder. Check if you have git files like that in folders containing your project.

Comment: Thanks for answering.  How do you check to make sure there isn't a .git file?  I'm really new to this.