# How to get super project root directory?

Tags: git, git-submodules

[Is there a way to get the git root directory in one command?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/957978/2748513) shows how to get the root of the current git tree, but if I have a super project (say the directory is: /a/b/mySuper) and submodule directories sub1, sub2 and sub3 underneath, How to get the root directory of the super project ("/a/b/mySuper" in this case) when my current `$PWD` being '/a/b/mySuper/sub2/dir1', if I run `git rev-parse --show-toplevel` from '/a/b/mySuper/sub2/dir1', it prints '/a/b/mySuper/sub2', instead I am looking for a command to print the top-super's directory '/a/b/mySuper'

Comment: A submodule (directory) may not even know it is a submodule. Furthermore, it may have several parent directories, if it's e.g. symlinked etc.

Comment: You should treat them as independent repositories or not use sub modules.

Answer (score 2):

```
git rev-parse --show-superproject-working-tree
```

I think this popped up in git 2.13.0.  Note that this only shows the immediate superproject and that nothing is printed to stdout when not called from within a submodule.