# How to check if the current repository is the top level git repo

Tags: git

I'm trying to check if the current repo is not a submodule but the top level 
git repository.  I have tried the following command: `git submodule init`

Output:

```
You need to run this command from the toplevel of the working tree.
```

But it will init the submodule. How can I check the current repository if it isn't a submodule but the top level git repository, without making a change in the repository?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to get the git root directory in one command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/957928/is-there-a-way-to-get-the-git-root-directory-in-one-command)

Answer (score 3):

You probably want `git rev-parse --show-superproject-working-tree`, with a fallback to `git rev-parse --show-toplevel` if you aren't in a submodule. For example:

```
toplevel=$(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)
superproject=$(git rev-parse --show-superproject-working-tree)

if [[ -z "$superproject" ]]; then
    echo "submodule in $superproject"
else
    echo "toplevel is $toplevel"
fi
```

I'm not currently aware of a builtin that provides an all-in-one answer for both situations.

Comment: `git rev-parse --show-superproject-working-tree` does not return any output , is it normal?

Comment: @alper Assuming you have a recent version of Git, the flag's documentation says (emph. mine): "Show the absolute path of the root of the superproject's working tree (if exists) that uses the current repository as its submodule. **Outputs nothing if the current repository is not used as a submodule by any project.**" So, no output could very well be the correct result.

Answer (score 2):

If you *do* use `git rev-parse --show-superproject-working-tree`, make sure to use Git 2.20 (Q4 2018), in order to avoid the error message "`returned path string doesn't match cwd`"

See [commit c5cbb27](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c5cbb27cb5f0a94ac5d0882778a00add829ad9d9) (27 Sep 2018) by [Sam McKelvie (`sammck`)](https://github.com/sammck).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit d152a74](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d152a74e2584dd0e235c9bcc97ef6a9ed239994a), 19 Oct 2018)</sup>

> ### `rev-parse`: --show-superproject-working-tree should work during a merge
>
> Invoking '`git rev-parse --show-superproject-working-tree`' exits with
>
> ```
> "fatal: BUG: returned path string doesn't match cwd?"
> ```
>
> when the superproject has an unmerged entry for the current submodule, instead of displaying the superproject's working tree.

(That was [first reported here](https://www.spinics.net/lists/git/msg342837.html))

> The problem is due to the fact that when a merge of the submodule reference
>   is in progress, "`git ls-files --stage —full-name <submodule-relative-path>`" returns three seperate entries for the submodule (one for each stage) rather than a single entry; e.g.,
>
> ```
> $ git ls-files --stage --full-name submodule-child-test
> 160000 dbbd2766fa330fa741ea59bb38689fcc2d283ac5 1       submodule-child-test
> 160000 f174d1dbfe863a59692c3bdae730a36f2a788c51 2       submodule-child-test
> 160000 e6178f3a58b958543952e12824aa2106d560f21d 3       submodule-child-test
> ```
>
> The code in [`get_superproject_working_tree()`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/c5cbb27cb5f0a94ac5d0882778a00add829ad9d9/submodule.c#L1987) expected exactly one entry to be returned;
>   [this patch](https://github.com/git/git/blob/c5cbb27cb5f0a94ac5d0882778a00add829ad9d9/submodule.c#L2041) makes it use the first entry if multiple entries are returned.