# Pushing to origin puts changed files in new directory

Tags: git, github

I am trying to push all my new files to a Github repo. However, it puts all the changed files in a new directory.

#### Example:

```sh
$ cd foobar
$ git add foo.txt
$ git add bar.txt
$ git add bax.txt
$ git commit -m "change some files"
$ git push origin master
```

Then I go to my Github repo, say, `foobarbaz`. Instead of all my changes going into the repo, a new folder is made called `foobar`. This folder contains all the files I added to the commit. Why is this?

Edit: "foobar" is the root dir of the repo (I know that it is too late to make this edit, but I thought new visitors should know)

Comment: is this a new repository you initialized or a cloned repository? My hunch is that this is a new repository you initialized using `git init` and you might have done `git init` from the parent of `foobar` directory (so `.git` folder is inside the parent) but did everything else (git add, commit etc.) after cd into foobar. Is this correct ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apperantly `.git` somehow moved out of my root dir. I have no idea how this happened, but a quick cut/paste did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Try and check your root folder for this local repository

```
cd .. # parent folder of foobar
git ls-files
```

If this works and you see:

```
foobar/foo.txt
foobar/bar.txt
...
```

That would  illustrates the root folder is not foobar, but its parent folder.
See also "[Is there a way to get the Git root directory in one command?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/957928/6309)"

```
git rev-parse --show-toplevel
```

That should show you where the root folder is.

You would need to recreate a `.git/` (`git init`) inside foobar, to get the proper result.
Then add the remote:

```
git remote add origin /url/remote/repository
```

Answer (score 0):

There is nowhere in the command you used where you used the foobarbaz rather I see you changed directory to foodbar and staged the text file food, bar and bax. I will suggest you check the name of repository you are using.

Comment: Say foo at is the root directory of the repo.