# GIT how to get the list of files to be committed with relative path

Tags: git, git-diff

If I execute:

```
$ git status
```

I get

```
Changes to be committed:
 (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

modified:   ../../resources/dags/BROKEN_DAG.py
modified:   ../../resources/dags/BROKEN_DAG2.py
```

But

```
$ git diff --cached --name-only
```

returns:

```
src/main/resources/dags/BROKEN_DAG.py
src/main/resources/dags/BROKEN_DAG2.py
```

How can I get something like this:

```
$ git diff --cached --name-only  --some-magic-option
../../resources/dags/BROKEN_DAG.py
../../resources/dags/BROKEN_DAG2.py
```

?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit-diff%5D+relative+path

Comment: I found also an alternative way to resolve my problem. 'git rev-parse --show-toplevel' returns the absolute path where the 'git diff --cached --name-only' are relative. So joining the paths I'm able to access the folder within my git hook.

Comment: You should have explained why do you need relative paths because my answer could be different: https://stackoverflow.com/a/957978/7976758, found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit-diff%5D+full+path