# How to get the absolute path of the repository directory in a post-receive hook

Tags: git, githooks

I am writing a Git post-receive hook, and within the hook script, I need the absolute path of the project directory (i.e. the directory of the repository). What is a reliable way to do this that works for both non-bare and bare repositories?

From my understanding, if the repository is bare (which I can check using `git rev-parse --is-bare-repository`), the absolute path can be obtained using `pwd`. If the repository is not bare, how can I reliably obtain the absolute path of the repository? Is it `dirname "$(pwd)"`? Is this method reliable?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to get the git root directory in one command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/957928/is-there-a-way-to-get-the-git-root-directory-in-one-command)

Comment: The top answer of the linked question *is reliable*.

Comment: @iBug No. All those answers assume that the repository in question is not bare.

Comment: @iBug In a bare repository, `git rev-parse --show-toplevel` in a post-receive hook will fail with exit code 128 and error message: `fatal: this operation must be run in a work tree`.

Comment: In a post-receive hook (or in a hook in general) `$GIT_DIR` points to the *repository* location. If you want the *working tree* location, don't use `$GIT_DIR`, but if you want the *repository* location, do use `$GIT_DIR`. To turn it into an absolute path, consider using `realpath`, though there are portability issues here.

Comment: You can use conditional statements in your script to handle different cases for bare repos and non-bare repos.

Comment: @iBug Yes, but is my proposed `dirname "$(pwd)"` method reliable?

Comment: @torek "In a post-receive hook (or in a hook in general) `$GIT_DIR` points to the repository location." Are you sure about this? In a non-bare repository, `$GIT_DIR` seems to point to the `.git/` directory of the repository.

Comment: Yes, "repository location" always refer to the `.git` directory, otherwise there wouldn't be a separate "working tree location".

Comment: Yes, as @iBug says, "repository location" means where the `HEAD` file, `objects/` directory, and so on reside. "Working tree" means where the user's work-tree resides. In a question like this it's important to keep in mind that there need not be any correlation between the two (when Git is invoked with `--git-dir` and `--work-tree` both, for instance).