# Git Pre-Commit hook for PHPCS is giving me error in Windows for Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, git, pre-commit-hook, phpcs

I have installed PHPCS from composer.json

```js
"require-dev": {
    "phpstan/phpstan": "^0.12.93",
    "squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "^3.6"
},
```

I am using laravel 8 so I have added below code for pre-commit file in `.git/hooks/pre-commit` file:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

# get bash colors and styles here: 
# http://misc.flogisoft.com/bash/tip_colors_and_formatting
C_RESET='\e[0m'
C_RED='\e[31m'
C_GREEN='\e[32m'
C_YELLOW='\e[33m'

function __run() #(step, name, cmd)
{
    local color output exitcode

    printf "${C_YELLOW}[%s]${C_RESET} %-20s" "$1" "$2"
    output=$(eval "$3" 2>&1)
    exitcode=$?

    if [[ 0 == $exitcode || 130 == $exitcode ]]; then
        echo -e "${C_GREEN}OK!${C_RESET}"
    else
        echo -e "${C_RED}NOK!${C_RESET}\n\n$output"
        exit 1
    fi
}

modified="git diff --diff-filter=M --name-only --cached  | grep \".php$\""
ignore="resources/lang,resources/views,bootstrap/helpers,database/migrations,bin"
phpcs="./vendor/bin/phpcs ./app --report=code --colors --report-width=80 --standard=PSR2 --ignore=${ignore}"

__run "1/3" "php lint" "${modified} | xargs -r php -l"
__run "2/3" "code sniffer" "${modified} | xargs -r ${phpcs}"
__run "3/3" "phpstan" "${modified} | xargs -r vendor/bin/phpstan analyse"
```

But this is giving me below error:

```
[2/3] code sniffer        NOK!

xargs: ./vendor/bin/phpcs: No such file or directory
```

**EDIT:**

Need to add below code

```
PROJECT=`php -r "echo dirname(dirname(dirname(realpath('$0'))));"`
STAGED_FILES_CMD=`git diff --cached --name-only --diff-filter=ACMR HEAD | grep \\\\.php`

# Determine if a file list is passed
if [ "$#" -eq 1 ]
then
    oIFS=$IFS
    IFS='
    '
    SFILES="$1"
    IFS=$oIFS
fi
SFILES=${SFILES:-$STAGED_FILES_CMD}

echo "Checking PHP Lint..."
echo $FILES;exit 1;
for FILE in $SFILES
do
    php -l -d display_errors=0 $PROJECT/$FILE
    if [ $? != 0 ]
    then
        echo "Fix the error before commit."
        exit 1
    fi
    FILES="$FILES $PROJECT/$FILE"
done

if [ "$FILES" != "" ]
then
```

Comment: Does `vendor/bin/phpcs` exist somewhere in the disk? Try its absolute path instead of relative path.

Comment: @ElpieKay so do I need to pass like D:\Xampp\htdocs\project\vendor\bin\phpcs ?

Comment: Try `/d/Xampp/htdocs/project/vendor/bin/phpcs`.

Comment: @ElpieKay same error with this path

Comment: Maybe end of file. try to open hook in vim and save.

Comment: which version of windows you are using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Worked code so that it would be useful to others:

```
#!C:/Program\ Files/Git/usr/bin/sh.exe

PROJECT=`php -r "echo dirname(dirname(realpath('$0')));"`

STAGED_FILES=$(git diff --cached --name-only --diff-filter=ACM | grep ".php\{0,1\}$")

if [[ "$STAGED_FILES" = "" ]]; then
  exit 0
fi

PASS=true

echo " Validating PHPCS:"

#doesnt matter where git was ran...just get absolute path to the .git folder
gitBase=`git rev-parse --absolute-git-dir`


# Check for phpcs
which ${gitBase}/../<path>/vendor/bin/phpcs &> /dev/null
if [[ "$?" == 1 ]]; then
  echo " Please install PHPCS "
  exit 1
fi

RULESET="$PROJECT/.githooks/ruleset.xml"

for FILE in $STAGED_FILES
do
  ${gitBase}/../<path>/vendor/bin/phpcs --colors --standard="$RULESET"  -n -p "$FILE"

  if [[ "$?" == 0 ]]; then
    echo "PHPCS Passed: $FILE "
  else
    echo "PHPCS Failed: $FILE "
    PASS=false
  fi
done

echo " PHPCS validation completed! "

if ! $PASS; then
  echo " COMMIT FAILED:  Your commit contains files that should pass PHPCS but do not. Please fix the PHPCS errors and try again. "
  exit 1
else
  echo " COMMIT SUCCEEDED "
fi

exit $?
```

and ruleset.xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ruleset name="PHP_CodeSniffer">
    <description>The coding standard for our project.</description>
    <rule ref="PSR2" />

    <file>app</file>
    <file>bootstrap</file>
    <file>config</file>
    <file>database</file>
    <file>resources</file>
    <file>routes</file>
    <file>tests</file>

    <exclude-pattern>bootstrap/cache/*</exclude-pattern>
    <exclude-pattern>bootstrap/autoload.php</exclude-pattern>
    <exclude-pattern>*/migrations/*</exclude-pattern>
    <exclude-pattern>*/seeds/*</exclude-pattern>
    <exclude-pattern>*.blade.php</exclude-pattern>
    <exclude-pattern>*.js</exclude-pattern>
    <exclude-pattern>tests/*</exclude-pattern>
    <!-- Show progression -->
    <arg value="p"/>
</ruleset>
```

Answer (score 0):

This hook comes from "[How to setup Git commit hooks for PHP](https://dev.to/bdelespierre/how-to-setup-git-commit-hooks-for-php-42d1) " from [Benjamin Delespierre](https://twitter.com/bdelespierre).

You have a similar example in [fdemiramon gist](https://gist.github.com/fdemiramon/0423b4308218d417fbf3), with the [comment](https://gist.github.com/fdemiramon/0423b4308218d417fbf3#gistcomment-1452287):

> Assumed that you have both `phpcs` and `phpcbf` in `bin/` folder.
> Best practice is to use the dedicated package for phpcs: [`squizlabs/PHP_CodeSniffer`](https://github.com/squizlabs/PHP_CodeSniffer)

That means: include a dependency for `squizlabs/php_codesniffer` in your `composer.json` file (which you did).
For example:

```json
{
    "require-dev": {
        "squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "3.*"
    }
}
```

> You will then be able to run `PHP_CodeSniffer` from the `vendor` `bin` directory:

```sh
./vendor/bin/phpcs -h
./vendor/bin/phpcbf -h
```

If using the full path (`/d/Xampp/htdocs/project/vendor/bin/phpcs`) does not work, even tough, in a git bash shell, `ls /d/Xampp/htdocs/project/vendor/bin/phpcs` does work, do check, as commented, the end of lines used for that file.
You can get the root folder with, as I [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/958125/6309), `git rev-parse --git-dir`.

Comment: Yes, ls /d/Xampp/htdocs/project/vendor/bin/phpcs is working,

Comment: D:/Xampp/htdocs/proj/.git -> this is my git path and D:/Xampp/htdocs/proj/api/v2/composer.json path

Comment: and vendor is in /d/Xampp/htdocs/proj/api/v2/vendor/bin/phpcs

Answer (score 0):

I hope you just forget to run `composer install` after adding require-dev to composer.

but I have made the hook you have posted in my `./.git/hooks/pre-commit` and try to commit `.php` files.
and I had got no error.

either i have `pwd` in the hook script function and it print **the project root directory**. and everything seems fine.
since.

from your comment i just think you are running on windows:

you have to write this:

```
#!C:/Program\ Files/Git/usr/bin/sh.exe
```

instead of unix shebang:

```
#!/bin/sh
```

---

### Desired Path

The desired git repository initialized & composer initialize is your **project base directory**

suppose this is your base directory: `/d/Xampp/htdocs/proj/`,
then your composer generated should be under this directory:

```
/d/Xampp/htdocs/proj/composer.json
/d/Xampp/htdocs/proj/composer.lock
/d/Xampp/htdocs/proj/vendor/
```

Also,
your `.git` directoy should be in this directory:

```
/d/Xampp/htdocs/proj/.git/
```

from the posted result from pwd, I think your git directory is under the:

```
/d/Xampp/htdocs/proj/api/v2/.git/
```

so i suggest to delete the `/d/Xampp/htdocs/proj/api/v2/.git/` directory,
then go to the  `cd D:\\Xampp\htdocs\proj`,
and `git init`,
it should create a new `.git` directory under `D:\\Xampp\htdocs\proj`.

### Change Directory from the script

the `pwd` prints the **current directory**, It seems when hook script start to run its path is what pwd has been reported.

you can add this lien before the line `output=...`

```
cd ../..
pwd
```

if the printed tab is somewhere else instead of your project base directory, you can change directory with the `cd` .

Comment: added #!C:/Program\ Files/Git/usr/bin/sh.exe in pre-commit hook first line, though same error

Comment: @bhumiShah what is the `pwd` command output ? please add before the `output= ...` line. and comment the result for me

Comment: pwd command output is /d/Xampp/htdocs/proj/api/v2

Comment: I have updated the answer based on your `pwd` result

Comment: my .git directory is on path D:\Xampp\htdocs\proj but my composer files are on D:\Xampp\htdocs\proj\api\v2

Comment: your assumption is wrong. I have given my paths and still getting same error

Comment: the `pwd` prints the **current directory**, It seems when hook script start to run its path is what pwd has been reported.

Comment: check if you can fix this with putting `cd` in the script

Comment: it should check file added for commit and if any error should shay not ok

Comment: Edited question. Do I need to pass files?

Comment: yes @bhumiShah, your problem for the **path** has been solved. and it dosent produce error. The script you have provided on my system generate success message. this is the second problem, and I think this line `modified="git diff --diff-filter=M --name-only --cached  | grep \".php$\""` dosent pass the php files.

Comment: i am going to investigate on this tomorrow night and tell you what is happening