# How do I get the root directory in one command?

Tags: version-control, sapling

In Git, I can get the root directory from any subdirectory like this:

```
git rev-parse --show-toplevel
```

From here: [Is there a way to get the git root directory in one command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/957928/is-there-a-way-to-get-the-git-root-directory-in-one-command/957978#957978)

Unfortunately this same command does not work in a repo cloned with [Sapling](https://sapling-scm.com/), it just returns the current directory.

Could someone tell me how to do this with Sapling, ideally with a similarly simple one-liner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Sapling, it is simply `sl root`.

Note that Sapling has in-product help for finding the analogue to a Git command via `sl git`. In this case, `sl git -- rev-parse --show-toplevel` returns `sl root`, as desired.