# How to get the full file path up to a specific directory in the path?

Tags: powershell

I have a path, such as `D:\repos\my-repo\some\script\path.ps1`, and I want to get the path just up to the repo name: `D:\repos\my-repo`. What's the best way to accomplish this? Here's what I've got right now:

```
$fullPath = $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path # D:\repos\my-repo\some\script\path.ps1
"{0}my-repo" -f [regex]::Split($fullPath, 'my-repo')[0]
```

This works but it's pretty ugly and inefficient in my opinion. Is there a better way to accomplish this?

Comment: If you're trying to find the root of a git repository, you can get that from git directly: https://stackoverflow.com/a/957978/5747548

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't see what's inefficient about what you currently have but here are 2 different ways you could accomplish the same.

```
$path = 'D:\repos\my-repo\some\script\path.ps1'
$path -replace '(?<=my-repo)\\.*'
```

Details on: https://regex101.com/r/ZkdlCR/1

```
$path = 'D:\repos\my-repo\some\script\path.ps1'
$path -replace '(?:\\[^\\]*){3}$'
```

Details on: https://regex101.com/r/6gk4MF/1

If you were looking for the object oriented approach you could also cast `FileInfo` to your path and then get the parent directory of the file (`.Directory`) and from there you can use the `.Parent` property to traverse it.

```
$path = 'D:\repos\my-repo\some\script\path.ps1'
([System.IO.FileInfo] $path).Directory.Parent.Parent.FullName
```

Comment: I guess I was hoping there would be a .NET method that can accomplish it without regex. Something like `[System.IO.Path]::GetSpecificDirectoryPath('D:\repos\my-repo\some\script\path.ps1', 'my-repo')`. Worst comes to worst, your first option works great so I'll go with that.

Comment: @jerdub1993 I added the .NET way you could do it. Path API doesnt offer a way to get specifically what you're looking for in this case

Comment: Unfortunately the path is variable, so no way of knowing how many "`.Parent`s" are needed to get to the repo directory. I'll go with the regex method.

Comment: @jerdub1993 yep, has the same problem as the 2nd regex and why I put the lookbehind method as first since its the more robust way to get it.

Answer (score 1):

Another regex solution:

```
$path = 'D:\repos\my-repo\some\script\path.ps1'
($path -split '(?<=\\my-repo)\\')[0]
```

- **Output:**

```
PS > $path = 'D:\repos\my-repo\some\script\path.ps1'
PS >
PS > ($path -split '(?<=\\my-repo)\\')[0]
D:\repos\my-repo
PS >
PS > $path = 'D:\repos\anotehrLevel\my-repo\some\script\path.ps1'
PS >
PS > ($path -split '(?<=\\my-repo)\\')[0]
D:\repos\anotehrLevel\my-repo
```