# Managing multiple repositories with git - inspect changes and record state

Tags: git, multiple-repositories

My git workflow consists of making changes to the working directory then firing up the gui, selecting changes, committing them and then pushing. The git gui is an awesome way of inspecting the changes along *a set of files at once.*

Gradually I started creating more projects (eclipse) and while I mostly work on one or two I now need to inspect the changes in all the repositories, and firing up 7 git guis is getting out of hand. Ideally I would like to be able to record a "master commit" - so when I push my main project at the remote repo to have a way of recording the state of the library projects at this time.

But my most urgent need is to be able to *inspect the changes in all the projects* **at once**. Surely there is a way ?

Related but not duplicates - bear in mind that I can dispose of all requirements *but being able to inspect the changes at once* while most other questions are about more fancy stuff :

- [Is it possible to manage multiple repositories coherently?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9136085/is-it-possible-to-manage-multiple-repositories-coherently)
- [Managing many git repositories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/816619/managing-many-git-repositories)

Please also note that I had a look at [submodules](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules) (the subdirectory structure is not an option, my projects are eclipse projects in the same workspace), but can't really wrap my brains around them.

Comment: What is the relation between these projects? If one of them are used like libraries in others, submodules are made just for that.

Comment: @golergka: well - some are libraries, some are models, some are test projects, there is a servlet etc. They are all under my control. Even if submodules is made for that I can't really see how I should use them :). In all I have a simple requirement : be able to inspect changes in all projects at once - and optionally be able to record a master commit somewhere - like "push to github 2013.11.05.16.09"

Comment: Why don't you unite them into one git repository then?