# Pushing all branches on GitLab fails after pushing single branch

Tags: gitlab

I have multiple independent branches in local repository, that I want to push to new remote repo on gitlab. But when I use `git push -u origin -all`, operation keeps failing after uploading a single branch. I have just created new repository on gitlab without changing anything or adding any hooks. Anything I can do to make sure all my branches will be pushed to remote repository, because I will often be pushing multiple branches. (Branches are independent because those changes come from team members who don't use git)

I tried exact same thing on github, and all branches were pushed without any issues.

Following is output I get when I run this command for gitlab,

```
$ git push -u origin --all
Counting objects: 582, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (582/582), done.
Writing objects: 100% (582/582), 210.92 KiB | 2.42 MiB/s, done.
Total 582 (delta 456), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (456/456), completed with 71 local objects.
error executing git hookerror executing git hookfatal: ref updates aborted by hook
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very recent (August 2020) and followed by [`gitlab-org/gitlab` issue 233964](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/233964)

The hook itself is triggered by [`cmd/gitaly-hooks/hooks.go`](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitaly/blob/f0cf8e59e5f0e72d2a2eb53d0846d2262d2808f9/cmd/gitaly-hooks/hooks.go#L70-73)

But, GitLab using the recent Git 2.27 and planing for Git 2.28, it is faced with [the new `reference-transaction` hook](https://github.com/git/git/blob/6c18d03eb833bb76d0072373bd064e469a022d4f/Documentation/githooks.txt#L410-L424) (which was [introduced in Git 2.27, June 2020](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61564736/6309)):

> This hook is invoked by any Git command that performs reference updates.
> It executes whenever a reference transaction is prepared, committed or aborted and may thus get called multiple times.

The thread adds:

> Due to performance concerns, the `reference-transaction` hook is using a cache so it doesn't have to repeatedly find the hook path again.
> But in case another hook is getting executed as part of the process, then the cache now points to that second hook instead of the first.

Try and see if using `git push --no-verify -all` would help, as a temporary workaround.

This leads to [`gitlab-org/gitlab-git` issue 1144](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-git/-/issues/1144) where [**Patrick Steinhardt**](https://gitlab.com/pks-t) has [sent a fix upstream (meaning to `git/git` mailing list)](https://public-inbox.org/git/63fb363375b515b903ed1269d10124b727c1d1cc.1596783732.git.ps@pks.im/T/#u).

> In order to not repeatedly search for the `reference-transaction` hook in case it's getting called multiple times, we use a caching mechanism to only call `find_hook()` once.
> What was missed though is that the return value of `find_hook()` actually comes from a `static strbuf`, which means it will get overwritten when calling `find_hook()` again.
> As a result, we may call the wrong hook with parameters of the `reference-transaction` hook.
>
> This scenario was spotted in the wild when executing a `git-push` with multiple references, where there are interleaving calls to both the update and the reference-transaction hook.
> While initial calls to the `reference-transaction` hook work as expected, it will stop working after the next invocation of the `update` hook.
> The result is that we now start calling the update hook with parameters and stdin of the `reference-transaction` hook.
>
> This commit fixes the issue by storing a copy of `find_hook()`'s return
> value in the cache.

The [OP Zorro Here](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4572871/zorro-here) adds [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63296183/pushing-all-branches-on-gitlab-fails-after-pushing-single-branch#comment111927699_63296495):

> hopefully GitLab will temporarily fix it from their end

Patrick also addresses that point in [MR 2454](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitaly/-/merge_requests/2454)

> There's a bug in the reference-transaction implementation in git-core
> which will cause interleaving calls to the `reference-transaction` hook to
> execute another hook by accident.
>
> While a fix has been proposed upstream, the earliest it may be available is with Git v2.28.1.
> So let's remove our reference-transaction hook for now to not expose this broken
> behaviour.
>
> I'm disabling this hook in Gitaly so that we can move ahead with the upgrade to Git v2.28.0.
> Reverting all the different MRs towards that version would be a major pain.

---

Note, regarding that reference-transaction hook, Git 2.32 (Q2 2021) is more explicit:

See [commit 23c781f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/23c781f1731bb77c16fb9c9a37e9d88f707af9bd), [commit 5f308a8](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5f308a89d8c37a186d58beff88542df00bc67975) (01 Mar 2021) by [Patrick Steinhardt (`pks-t`)](https://github.com/pks-t).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 20adca9](https://github.com/git/git/commit/20adca90064fe4e8b5fcff312e74ff2e1a407bd2), 22 Mar 2021)</sup>

> ### [`githooks.txt`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/23c781f1731bb77c16fb9c9a37e9d88f707af9bd): clarify documentation on reference-transaction hook
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Patrick Steinhardt</sup>

> The reference-transaction hook doesn't clearly document its scope and what values it receives as input.
> Document it to make it less surprising and clearly delimit its (current) scope.

`githooks` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/23c781f1731bb77c16fb9c9a37e9d88f707af9bd/Documentation/githooks.txt#L476-L477):

> The hook
> does not cover symbolic references (but that may change in the future).

`githooks` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/23c781f1731bb77c16fb9c9a37e9d88f707af9bd/Documentation/githooks.txt#L496-L503):

> For each reference update that was added to the transaction, the hook
> receives on standard input a line of the format:
>
> ```
> <old-value> SP <new-value> SP <ref-name> LF
> ```
>
> where:
>
> - `<old-value>` is the old object name passed into the reference
>   transaction,
> - `<new-value>` is the new object name to be stored in the
>   ref and
> - `<ref-name>` is the full name of the ref.
>
> When force updating the reference regardless of its current value or when the reference is to be created anew, `<old-value>` is the all-zeroes object name.
> To distinguish these cases, you can inspect the current value of
> `<ref-name>` via `git rev-parse`.

Comment: Same issue using `git push --no-verify --all`. But thanks, good to know I am not the only one facing this issue.

Comment: @ZorroHere OK. This seems a consequence of GitLab using Git 2.27: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61564736/6309

Comment: @ZorroHere A fix is in the way (but will have to wait for Git 2.29 next november, or possibly a Git 2.28.x later this month at the earliest)

Comment: thanks for update, hopefully GitLab will temporarily fix it from their end.

Comment: @ZorroHere Yes, Patrick  Steinhardt (from GitLab) is fixing the (GitLab) gitaly issue as we speak: see my latest edit on my answer.

Answer (score 0):

try skipping the branch pushed, maybe this generate conflicts

Comment: How to skip pushed branch? Thing is, I have to keep running this command until all branches are uploaded. It quits after uploading single branch on each run.