# Pushing multiple repositories in a single command to bitbucket

Tags: git, bitbucket

I am an absolute newbee to bitbucket and git. I am working in a small company with 5 employees. We are storing multiple git repositories in a local server( in /home/user/git/project1, project2... projectn) for each project. I want to back it up in bitbucket. How can I push all project repos in a single command?

Comment: see [Managing many git repositories](http://stackoverflow.com/q/816619)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. write a shell script that runs `git push` multiple times, once for each repo
2. make the shell script executable and make sure it's in your path
3. the shell script is your single command