# How to Clone all repositories into Team from Bitbucket using GIT

Tags: git, clone, bitbucket, repository

i want to know if it's possible to clone all repositories in a team from bitbucket since git.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think GIT supports this natively, however there is an endpoint where you can grab all repos for a particular team, outlined here - https://bitbucket.org/site/master/issue/7659/use-api-to-get-repositories-by-team-name ( For example, Atlassian's repositories: https://bitbucket.org/!api/1.0/users/atlassian ).  I'll bet there's a way with some elbow grease to use the results of that API with this somehow - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18900294/checkout-multiple-git-repositories-in-one-local-directory

Answer (score 8):

I've made up [this tiny Ruby script](https://gist.github.com/mgarciaisaia/46d0fb26c48746eb53c7). Test it and **remove the `echo` from within the `system()` call for it to actually do the cloning**.

```ruby
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

# USAGE: ./clone ORG_NAME
# ( ./clone instedd )
require 'open-uri'
require 'json'

team = ARGV[0] || raise("Must specify organization name")

puts "Fetching https://bitbucket.org/!api/1.0/users/#{team}..."

data = JSON.parse(open("https://bitbucket.org/!api/1.0/users/#{team}").read)

data["repositories"].each do | repo |
  # delete "echo" for _actually_ cloning them
  system("echo #{repo["scm"]} clone https://bitbucket.org/#{team}/#{repo["slug"]}")
end
```

Comment: What about `ssh keys`?

Comment: @Shamoon, the script uses the `https` protocol, so there is no ssh connection. You can tune the `system()` like to meet your needs - that just runs `$VCS clone $URL` for each of the repositories. Do you have any specific issue that makes you ask about those keys?

Comment: Well, I am trying to clone for users of my service

Comment: Do you know how to find the org name if you have a self hosting bitbucket server ?

Comment: @tyrell_c if you're talking about Attlassian's Stash, then it seems you have something called a Project, in which you put repositories. Check the [REST API docs](https://developer.atlassian.com/static/rest/stash/3.11.6/stash-rest.html#idp2971616) to get an idea - I don't use Stash, so I can't really help there.

Answer (score 2):

[git_cloner](https://github.com/artiomn/git_cloner) is a free and open-source tool that I have developed to clone a bunch of BitBucket or GitHub repositories.

Example:

```
git_cloner --type bitbucket --login user --password password https://my_bitbucket
```

Use REST API:

1. Get JSON with all projects:
   `http://my_bitbucket/rest/api/1.0/projects`

   Or:
   `http://my_bitbucket/rest/api/1.0/<user>/projects`
2. Get JSON with repositories for every project:

   ```
   http://my_bitbucket/rest/api/1.0/projects/<project_name>/repos?limit=10000
   ```
3. Clone repos by `['links']['clone']['href']` parameter from the JSON.

Full example: https://github.com/artiomn/git_cloner/blob/master/src/git_cloner/bitbucket.py

Comment: Thanks for improving this. However, if you are the author of this tool, we require that you [disclose your affiliation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion). I couldn't tell for sure if you are affiliated with it or not, but it looks like it.

Comment: Yes, it's my tool with a free licence.

Answer (score 0):

1. download [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/)
2. fetch https://bitbucket.org/!api/1.0/users/[teamslug] w/ authed browser inspect cookies, and find the bb_session cookie
3. exec the following replacing [teamslug] and [bb_cookie]

`A=[teamslug]; BBCOKIE=[bb_cookie]; for repo in $(curl -s -o 'https://bitbucket.org/!api/1.0/users/$A' | jq --raw-output '.repositories[].slug'); do echo git clone https://bitbucket.org/$A/$repo >> all_team_repos; done`

4. sh all_team_repos

Answer (score 0):

For hg i used follow script, you can use it for git

```py
import getpass
import requests
import urllib.parse
import json
import os

username = input('Username: ')
password = getpass.getpass("Password: ")

params = {
    "pagelen": 100
}
url = "https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/%s" % username
url = url + "?" + urllib.parse.urlencode(params)
repos_data = requests.get(url, auth=(username, password))

repos_data = json.loads(repos_data.content)


for repo in repos_data["values"]:
    os.system("hg clone %s" % repo["links"]["clone"][1]["href"])
```