# Run hg pull over all subdirectories

Tags: ubuntu, mercurial, multiple-repositories

How can I update multiple mercurial (hg) repositories from their shared parent's directory?

```
/plugins/search
/plugins/overview
/plugins/chart
```

I want to change a branch to default one and update them all at once

```
cd /plugins/search
hg update -C default
hg pull -u
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run the following from the parent directory, `plugins` in this case:

```
find . -type d -maxdepth 1 -exec hg update -C default -R {} \;
find . -type d -maxdepth 1 -exec hg pull -u -R {} \;
```

To clarify:

- `find .` searches the current directory
- `-type d` to find directories, not files
- `-maxdepth 1` for a maximum depth of one sub-directory
- `-exec {} \;` runs a custom command for every find
- `hg update -C default -R {}` hg changes branch to default in each repository
- `hg pull -u -R {}` hg updates to new branch head if changesets were pulled in each repository

Answer (score 2):

## Finding repositories deeper in the directory tree

```
find . -type d -iname .hg -exec echo \; -exec hg pull -u -R {}/.. \;
```

The initial `-exec echo \;` is only there to keep the output clean.

Click here for [more `find` galore](http://hamwaves.com/find/en/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

Run this command on your root directory of project which is **plugin**

> find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -print -execdir git --git-dir={}/.git --work-tree=$PWD/{} pull origin develop;