# Git Client Software to Pull Several Remote Repositories at Once

Tags: git, github, bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree, gitkraken

I'm following ( what are new changes ) and working on several github/bitbucket repositories.

If I will work on a project; almost every time I need to pull changes from remote branch, that's okay. But when you have a lot of repositories to **work & watch**, it's painful to repeat.

Is there any git client to pull several repositories at one click ?

Here is my current bad solution ( for linux script, pull.sh ):

```
cd /home/username/Codes/Github/quozd/awesome-dotnet && git pull
cd /home/username/Codes/Github/servicestack/ServiceStack && git pull
cd /home/username/Codes/Github/aspnet/AspNetCore.git && git pull
...
```

Obviously I don't recommend this approach, because;

- you need to add a new line if you added a new repository to watch,
- hard too see which files have been changed.
- can't see commit comments. I want to see commit/check-in comments 
  etc.

I don't see any feature like this in git clients: SourceTree, GitKraken. Also, it's painfull to click every repositories one by one and click pull. It's too much approach for a daily job to do. I need a git client software to do this, Windows and/or Linux.

I don't know how this question marked as "duplicate of question x". I asked a git client, git client that has gui to pull changes from several remote repositories & **see commit comments** with one click.

This question is not talking about commit comments -> [Managing many git repositories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/816619/managing-many-git-repositories)

Comment: Maybe http://mixu.net/gr/ will fit your needs.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+work+with+many+repositories+at+once

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a tool called "[RepoZ](https://github.com/awaescher/RepoZ)" which automatically discovers git repositories as soon as you clone them or change anything in them like switching a branch.

**Let me put this first: There's nothing you have to do in this application to keep your information up to date. Each dev decision was met to build a zero-effort app as far as possible.**

Once found, the repositories are "tracked". That will simply show them in a list of local repositories including a dense status information. This contains the current branch and further stuff like file edits and the count of incoming or outgoing commits.

I found that very handy to keep track of uncommited work.

[image: RepoZ UI]

Having that list, I thought that I could use it for more things like repository navigation. I cannot count all the times I opened and endless list of Explorer/Finder windows to switch between repositories. In fact, searching for the correct one took more time that opening a new one more often that I would like to admit.

Since each repository RepoZ tracks contains its directory, it's actually very easy to use that as a central springboard for our beloved decentralized git repositories:

[image: RepoZ Navigation]

## But "... Pull Several Remote Repositories at Once"?

Now, I write that because I think it also provides that feature that you asked for. The great [twenzel](https://github.com/twenzel) added [an improvement idea](https://github.com/awaescher/RepoZ/issues/52) I implemented lately: "Auto fetch"

[image: RepoZ Auto-Fetch]

With that, you can tell RepoZ to automatically fetch the remotes of all your git repositories. For me, that's a great addition because then, RepoZ automatically updates the status information with the count of incoming commits.

And best of all: There's nothing to do for you. No manually fetches, it's all done in the background. These fetches won't collide with your local commits, of course. There are no local merge attempts like with `git pull`.

I'd love to hear from you whether this did help.

Comment: I don't know why somebody downgraded this answer; This is so close what I need. Thanks for your effort and this tool. I think only one missing feature is ( what I'm looking up to ) see a brief summary of commit comments. An example, user tracking/working on 3 remote repositories. User clicks auto-fetch-all button and a window opens in fullscreen; RepositoryName \n BranchName \n CommitId \n Commit Comments. Ofcourse files and a diff compare would be awesome, but hard to code it. Anyway, thanks for this. I will follow this project.

Comment: I don't know either. I don't know why some guys downvoted your question at all. Perhaps you just don't use git in the way they think is the right one ... well ... Anyway, I don't plan to add pull logs or even diffs to RepoZ, I want it to be quiet. But hey, clone RepoZ and use the infrastructure I built to implement your features. You can easily extend the context menu in the Windows version. Then, you could mark all repositories in RepoZ with CTRL+A and invoke your new action from there.